# Use 'import module' or 'from module import'?

Tags: python, python-import

I've tried to find a comprehensive guide on whether it is best to use `import module` or `from module import`. I've just started with Python and I'm trying to start off with best practices in mind.

Basically, I was hoping if anyone could share their experiences, what preferences other developers have and what's the best way to avoid any *gotchas* down the road?

Comment: I just wanted to let you know, that the selected answer is wrong. It states that the difference is subjective whereas there is a difference. This could possibly lead to hard to detect bugs. See Michael Ray Lovetts answer.

Comment: Related post - [Reasoning behind `from … import …` syntax in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3600352/465053) & ['import module' vs. 'from module import function'](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/187403/236257)

Comment: **There's a hell of a difference between importing specific named identifiers `'from module import X,Y,Z` vs `'from module import *`**. The latter pollutes your namespace and can give unpredictable results depending on what's going on in module. Worse still is doing `from module import *` with multiple modules.

Comment: The Python Language does not have standart, but there is a nice book, which from Python 3.* is mostly as Python Reference written originally by Gvinno Van Rossum (author of the language): https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: For sublte and complete description how import system is working you can read a dedicated section from https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html, specifically, it is: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: Another document: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-import-statement describes various statements, and from that document there is a description for logic of work for `import` and `from` statements description.

Comment: This post gives some speed benchmarks between `import module` and from `module import x`: https://towardsdatascience.com/6-bad-manners-makes-your-python-program-slower-15b6fce62927 personally I could not reproduce them and it seems that the speed is the same. So probably the answer depends actually on ease of maintenance and name space potential issues as described by some answers

Comment: Obviously, the python import system is a nightmare, and the best advice for beginners is just "try stuff and see how it works - if it's confusing and frustrating, that's normal."

In some cases there are meaningful differences in the way you import things, sometimes it's mostly just taste.

Best bet: do it in the way that works, but try to have a reason for it

Comment: @NathanChappell On the contrary: the python import system is powerful and the default configuration is elegant. There are very few specific things that need to be understood in order to use it properly, and they are easy to explain. The only actual problems are a) the Internet is full of people explaining them wrongly; b) people want it to work differently than how it actually does (for example, the way it works in Java, or in JavaScript).

Comment: **people want it to work differently than how it actually does**

Answer (score 623, accepted):

The difference between `import module` and `from module import foo` is mainly subjective.  Pick the one you like best and be consistent in your use of it.  Here are some points to help you decide.

`import module`

- **Pros:**

  - Less maintenance of your `import` statements. Don't need to add any additional imports to start using another item from the module
- **Cons:**

  - Typing `module.foo` in your code can be tedious and redundant (tedium can be minimized by using `import module as mo` then typing `mo.foo`)

`from module import foo`

- **Pros:**

  - Less typing to use `foo`
  - More control over which items of a module can be accessed
- **Cons:**

  - To use a new item from the module you have to update your `import` statement
  - You lose context about `foo`. For example, it's less clear what `ceil()` does compared to `math.ceil()`

Either method is acceptable, but **don't** use `from module import *`.

For any reasonable large set of code, if you `import *` you will likely be cementing it into the module, unable to be removed.  This is because it is difficult to determine what items used in the code are coming from 'module', making it easy to get to the point where you think you don't use the `import` any more but it's extremely difficult to be sure.

Comment: +1 for discouraging usage of "from module import *", it just clutters the namespace.

Comment: cluttering the namespace is *not* the most problematic part of "import *", it's the reduction in readability: Any name conflicts will show themselves in (unit) testing. But all the names you use from the imported module will be bare, with nary a hint were they come from.  I absolutely loathe "import *".

Comment: Doesn't the Zen of Python say explicit is better than implicit?

Comment: `from module import *` can be particularly useful, if using it as: `if(windows):\n\t from module_win import * \n else: \n\t from module_lin import *`. Then your parent module can potentially contain OS independent function names, if the function names in module_lin & module_win have same names. It's like conditionally inheriting either class.

Comment: -1: The difference is not mainly subjective. It actually changes semantics in some cases. (That's a fact, though I have no idea why it works this way.) See this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20863145/1143274

Comment: @anishsane. There is another way do it. import module_win as something.    Then always use something.method_name()

Comment: One semantic difference is that for immutable objects, `from mod import foo` creates a new `foo`, whereas `import mod; mod.foo` uses the same `foo` object as the one in `mod`.  But `foo` should probably be hidden behind accessors anyway.

Comment: Another pro for `from module import foo`: to **announce a weak dependency**. When you need a module that's not in the standard library just for one tiny foo in it, this shows for posterity that the dependency could be removed by refactoring the use of foo.

Comment: How about importing `*` when working with a framework rather than a module? Like, every code using tkinter starts with `from tkinter import *`, would you consider it bad practice and recommend `import tkinter` instead?

Comment: import * is overused. But that doesn't mean it should never be used. It's a particularly useful shortcut when using small modules for projects that do not need to scale up that much. For example I like `from turtle import *`

Comment: @Rightleg I've seen `import tkinter as tk`, maybe that answers your question?

Comment: @MarkRansom Hm, not really. While I know `import as` and don't really see any downside to it, I'm rather wondering how bad it would be to `import *` when working with a single big library.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev Your link does not demonstrate a difference in semantics between the import styles. It only shows that `import Image` is different from `from PIL import Image`. This has nothing to do with import style, it's a difference in the actual module structure. `from PIL import Image; Image` and `import PIL; PIL.Image` are equivalent; `import Image` is totally different.

Comment: One non-stylistic difference between the two styles that should be mentioned in this answer is that `from module import Thing` can cause circular-import ImportError (because it requires `module` to be fully executed right away) whereas `import module` would work without error in the same situation (as long as `module.Thing` is only accessed inside a function, not in import-time code).

Comment: Does it make any difference in a size of a module being imported? When I compile my souce file, is it the same to import one or the other way if I want to keep it smaller?

Comment: -1 This answer is wrong. There is a difference. See @Michael Ray Lovetts answer for the true answer. There is a **crucial** difference!

Comment: @Rightleg As you may have noticed I try to encourage the use of `import tkinter as tk` in most of my Tkinter answers. I strongly agree with Jürgen A. Erhard that the main issue with star imports is that they impact readability, since it means you have no easy way of seeing which names are local and which are imports. (And of course code that does multiple star imports is far worse on that score, plus you have the potential for name collision). I admit it's not so bad in Tkinter since you're mostly importing widget names, in Uppercase, which makes them stand out from local lowercase names.

Comment: @Rightleg (cont) However, a Tkinter star import does dump a *lot* of stuff into your namespace - 136 names in Python 3, and 175 names in Python 2! OTOH, trying to do stuff in `ctypes` _without_ a star import is madness. :)

Comment: I sometimes run into something like `import module.api as mod`. If I drop `.api`, it won't work. Is this a module-specific issue. If not, is there any broader explanation that applies to all python modules?

Comment: `from x.y import z
from x.y.z import foo

temp = z.SomeEnum.red
`
foo is the function.
SomeEnum is a Enum 

Is it ok to have import both the module and also a function in the same file?

Comment: It's extremely easy to determine what function are being used from a star import. I made a function to use pylint to do it for me, by scanning for every `W0614: Unused import` error and then subtracting those functions from the set of all functions imported from the module. What remains, is what needs to be imported. Works perfectly.

Comment: What's the difference between `from module import foo` and `from module import *`? (excuse me, I am relatively new to python)

Answer (score 291):

There's another detail here, not mentioned, related to writing to a module. Granted this may not be very common, but I've needed it from time to time.

Due to the way references and name binding works in Python, if you want to update some symbol in a module, say foo.bar, from outside that module, and have other importing code "see" that change, you have to import foo a certain way. For example:

module foo:

```
bar = "apples"
```

module a:

```
import foo
foo.bar = "oranges"   # update bar inside foo module object
```

module b:

```
import foo           
print foo.bar        # if executed after a's "foo.bar" assignment, will print "oranges"
```

However, if you import symbol names instead of module names, this will not work.

For example, if I do this in module a:

```
from foo import bar
bar = "oranges"
```

No code outside of `a` will see `bar` as "oranges" because my setting of `bar` merely affected the name "bar" inside module `a`, it did not "reach into" the `foo` module object and update its `bar`.

Comment: With that last example, can you still call 'foo.bar = "orange"' to update 'bar' inside 'foo'?

Comment: No, in the last example, the name 'foo' is unknown

Comment: THIS answer provides the "true" answer on the question: what is the difference between the two import variants

Comment: Wrote some snippet to prove this answer is absolutely right, but what's the rationale behind this?

Comment: I think what you are saying is import symbol names to have local variables but import module names to have global variables???

Comment: Hi Micheal, just wondering, do you know or have some reference explaining why this is the case? If we test variables imported either using `import m` or `from m import var` (`m.var is var` prints True) we can see that they are exactly the same variable so it seems at least they both should change values regardless of importation method. By the way, this answer should be the accepted one IMO.

Comment: This is not entirely true. The case illustrated is a result of strings being immutable. If instead "bar" was a list, then having say "foo.bar.append('oranges')" in module a, would be reflected when printing the list in module b.

Comment: @gateway2745 exactly. This is merely an example of shadowing. Functions requiring `global` have the same issue.

Comment: Although I agree with the technicality of this answer, I would like to point out that this is a bad practice. You should avoid changing global variables *as much as possible* to avoid very difficult to find bugs. Multiple modules changing a global variable exponentially increases this risk. Please never do this.

Comment: This is hugely important. Also @ChrisCollett The answer is helpful because without knowing that one changes the module globally, you might be changing the module globally without knowing it. So the answer helped me to stop changing the module globally where it already was.

Comment: @rohit_r I think it's not related to the immutability of the object. If you did `bar = [1,2,3]` that would also not be reflected in module b or foo. It's really because the `bar` imported by `from foo import  bar` is really a new reference to the object in module foo, and the assignment overwrites the local reference only while keeping the one in module foo untouched.

Comment: This is a bad answer, and is one of the reasons that using global variables is usually a bad idea.

When importing "from module import thing", a copy of "thing" is created in the current namespace.

When importing the module, we reference "thing" as "module.thing", and if we modify or replace it with a different value, that will affect all references to "module.thing".

Modifying global variables in one module from another module has a bad code smell and is prone to bugs.

Comment: This might explain some of the issues I'm having with reloading modules in a Jython environment contained in an application. If I use `import a.b.c as foo` to access a module, will other importing code "see" changes like it would if I simply did import `a.b.c`?

Answer (score 125):

Even though many people already explained about `import` vs `import from`, I want to try to explain a bit more about what happens under the hood, and where all the places it changes are.

---

### `import foo`:

Imports `foo`, and creates a reference to that module in the current namespace. Then you need to define completed module path to access a particular attribute or method from inside the module.

E.g. `foo.bar` but not `bar`

### `from foo import bar`:

Imports `foo`, and creates references to all the members listed (`bar`). Does not set the variable `foo`.

E.g. `bar` but not `baz` or `foo.baz`

### `from foo import *`:

Imports `foo`, and creates references to all public objects defined by that module in the current namespace (everything listed in `__all__` if `__all__` exists, otherwise everything that doesn't start with `_`). Does not set the variable `foo`.

E.g. `bar` and `baz` but not `_qux` or `foo._qux`.

---

Now let’s see when we do `import X.Y`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import os.path
```

Check `sys.modules` with name `os` and `os.path`:

```
>>> sys.modules['os']
<module 'os' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> sys.modules['os.path']
<module 'posixpath' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
```

Check `globals()` and `locals()` namespace dicts with `os` and `os.path`:

```
>>> globals()['os']
<module 'os' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> locals()['os']
<module 'os' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> globals()['os.path']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'os.path'
>>>
```

From the above example we found that only `os` is inserted in the local and global namespace.
So, we should be able to use:

```
>>> os
<module 'os' from
  '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> os.path
<module 'posixpath' from
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
>>>
```

But not `path`.

```
>>> path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
>>>
```

Once you delete the `os` from locals() namespace, you won't be able to access `os` as well as `os.path` even though they exist in sys.modules:

```
>>> del locals()['os']
>>> os
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
>>> os.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
>>>
```

## Now let's talk about `import from`:

### `from`:

```
>>> import sys
>>> from os import path
```

### Check `sys.modules` with `os` and `os.path`:

```
>>> sys.modules['os']
<module 'os' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.pyc'>
>>> sys.modules['os.path']
<module 'posixpath' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
```

We found that in `sys.modules` we found as same as we did before by using `import name`

OK, let's check how it looks like in `locals()` and `globals()` namespace dicts:

```
>>> globals()['path']
<module 'posixpath' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
>>> locals()['path']
<module 'posixpath' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
>>> globals()['os']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'os'
>>>
```

You can access by using name `path` not by `os.path`:

```
>>> path
<module 'posixpath' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
>>> os.path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
>>>
```

Let's delete 'path' from `locals()`:

```
>>> del locals()['path']
>>> path
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'path' is not defined
>>>
```

One final example using an alias:

```
>>> from os import path as HELL_BOY
>>> locals()['HELL_BOY']
<module 'posixpath' from '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
>>> globals()['HELL_BOY']
<module 'posixpath' from /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc'>
>>>
```

And no path defined:

```
>>> globals()['path']
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'path'
>>>
```

Comment: While this is verbose, this is really the best answer in the list for a fairly complex question.  It provides actual code to help explain the "under the hood" subtleties, which are more important than style, for this particular issue.  I wish I could upvote it more than once!

Comment: Does using `as SYMBOL` change how this answer works at all?

Answer (score 45):

Both ways are supported for a reason: there are times when one is more appropriate than the other.

- `import module`: nice when you are using many bits from the module. drawback is that you'll need to qualify each reference with the module name.
- `from module import ...`: nice that imported items are usable directly without module name prefix. The drawback is that you must list each thing you use, and that it's not clear in code where something came from.

Which to use depends on which makes the code clear and readable, and has more than a little to do with personal preference. I lean toward `import module` generally because in the code it's very clear where an object or function came from. I use `from module import ...` when I'm using some object/function a *lot* in the code.

Comment: Is there a way to use `from M import X` and still get the benefit of using the qualifiers somehow? It seems you could get the best of both worlds if you could still do `M.X`after that import.

Comment: @artgropod: Kinda. You can do `class m: from something.too.long import x, y, z`. Wouldn't really recommend that though.

Answer (score 35):

I personally always use

```
from package.subpackage.subsubpackage import module
```

and then access everything as

```
module.function
module.modulevar
```

etc. The reason is that at the same time you have short invocation, and you clearly define the module namespace of each routine, something that is very useful if you have to search for usage of a given module in your source.

Needless to say, do not use the import *, because it pollutes your namespace and it does not tell you where a given function comes from (from which module)

Of course, you can run in trouble if you have the same module name for two different modules in two different packages, like

```
from package1.subpackage import module
from package2.subpackage import module
```

in this case, of course you run into troubles, but then there's a strong hint that your package layout is flawed, and you have to rethink it.

Comment: In the last case, you can always use:
    import pkgN.sub.module as modN
giving you distinct names for each module. You can also use the 'import modulename as mod1' pattern to shorten a long name, or to switch between implementations of the same API (e.g. DB API modules) with a single name change.

Comment: When you use `pathlib`, do you always write it out as `pathlib.Path` ?

Answer (score 16):

```
import module
```

Is best when you will use many functions from the module.

```
from module import function
```

Is best when you want to avoid polluting the global namespace with all the functions and types from a module when you only need `function`.

Comment: Surely the only thing in the global namespace if you do 'import module' is 'module' ?  You only pollute the namespace if you do 'from .. import *'.

Answer (score 12):

I've just discovered one more subtle difference between these two methods.

If module `foo` uses a following import:

```
from itertools import count
```

Then module `bar` can by mistake use `count` as though it was defined in `foo`, not in `itertools`:

```
import foo
foo.count()
```

If `foo` uses:

```
import itertools
```

the mistake is still possible, but less likely to be made. `bar` needs to:

```
import foo
foo.itertools.count()
```

This caused some troubles to me. I had a module that by mistake imported an exception from a module that did not define it, only imported it from other module (using `from module import SomeException`). When the import was no longer needed and removed, the offending module was broken.

Answer (score 10):

Here is another difference not mentioned.  This is copied verbatim from http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Note that when using

```
from package import item
```

the item can be either a submodule (or subpackage) of the package, or some other name defined in the package, like a function, class or variable. The import statement first tests whether the item is defined in the package; if not, it assumes it is a module and attempts to load it. If it fails to find it, an ImportError exception is raised.

Contrarily, when using syntax like

```
import item.subitem.subsubitem
```

each item except for the last must be a package; the last item can be a module or a package but can’t be a class or function or variable defined in the previous item.

Comment: Another thing I noticed was that if item is also a submodule inside package then
 
"from package import item" 

works but 
"import package"

package.item.subitem=... 

does not work with an empty __init__.py of package, unless we have 
"import item"

in the __init__ file of package.

Answer (score 8):

Since I am also a beginner, I will be trying to explain this in a simple way:
In Python, we have three types of `import` statements which are:

**1. Generic imports:**

```
import math
```

*this type of import is my personal favorite, the only downside to this import technique is that if you need use any module's function you must use the following syntax:*

```
math.sqrt(4)
```

*of course, it increases the typing effort but as a beginner, it will help you to keep track of module and function associated with it, (a good text editor will reduce the typing effort significantly and is recommended).*

***Typing effort can be further reduced by using this import statement:***

```
import math as m
```

*now, instead of using `math.sqrt()` you can use `m.sqrt()`.*

**2. Function imports:**

```
from math import sqrt
```

*this type of import is best suited if your code only needs to access single or few functions from the module, but for using any new item from the module you have to update import statement.*

**3. Universal imports:**

```
from math import *
```

*Although it reduces typing effort significantly but is not recommended because it will fill your code with various functions from the module and their name could conflict with the name of user-defined functions.*
**example:**

#### If you have a function of your very own named sqrt and you import math, your function is safe: there is your sqrt and there is math.sqrt. If you do from math import *, however, you have a problem: namely, two different functions with the exact same name. Source: [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com)

Answer (score 7):

I would like to add to this. It can be useful to understand how Python handles imported modules as attributes if you run into circular imports.

I have the following structure:

```
mod/
    __init__.py
    main.py
    a.py
    b.py
    c.py
    d.py
```

From main.py I will import the other modules using differnt import methods

main.py:

```
import mod.a
import mod.b as b
from mod import c
import d
```

dis.dis shows the difference (note module names, a b c d):

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (-1)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              6 IMPORT_NAME              0 (mod.a)
              9 STORE_NAME               1 (mod)

  2          12 LOAD_CONST               0 (-1)
             15 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             18 IMPORT_NAME              2 (b)
             21 STORE_NAME               2 (b)

  3          24 LOAD_CONST               0 (-1)
             27 LOAD_CONST               2 (('c',))
             30 IMPORT_NAME              1 (mod)
             33 IMPORT_FROM              3 (c)
             36 STORE_NAME               3 (c)
             39 POP_TOP

  4          40 LOAD_CONST               0 (-1)
             43 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             46 IMPORT_NAME              4 (mod.d)
             49 LOAD_ATTR                5 (d)
             52 STORE_NAME               5 (d)
             55 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
```

In the end they look the same (STORE_NAME is result in each example), but this is worth noting if you need to consider the following four circular imports:

### example1

```
foo/
   __init__.py
   a.py
   b.py
```

```
a.py:
import foo.b
```

```
b.py:
import foo.a
```

```
>>> import foo.a
>>>
```

This works

### example2

```
bar/
   __init__.py
   a.py
   b.py
```

```
a.py:
import bar.b as b
```

```
b.py:
import bar.a as a
```

```
>>> import bar.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "bar\a.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bar.b as b
  File "bar\b.py", line 1, in <module>
    import bar.a as a
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'a'
```

No dice

### example3

```
baz/
   __init__.py
   a.py
   b.py
```

```
a.py:
from baz import b
```

```
b.py:
from baz import a
```

```
>>> import baz.a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "baz\a.py", line 1, in <module>
    from baz import b
  File "baz\b.py", line 1, in <module>
    from baz import a
ImportError: cannot import name a
```

Similar issue... but clearly from x import y is not the same as import import x.y as y

### example4

```
qux/
   __init__.py
   a.py
   b.py
```

```
a.py:
import b
```

```
b.py:
import a
```

```
>>> import qux.a
>>>
```

This one also works

Comment: Amazing fun fact! Can you explain the reason behind this?

Comment: Good question! I don't know the answer off the top of my head, but that sounds like a fun exercise of spelunking through python internals.

Comment: Only this answer provides some depth on the situation where the differences between the types of imports are so fundamental, that one is a "no go" (import-from), while other "works" (import, or from ... import *). Circular dependencies are unavoildable in some situations (e.g. where dependency injection is needed/used). For now it appears that import and from ... import * work as "include guards" in c++ (only need symbol names), but import-from statements actually require the target modules to be fully loaded. Need to get some more understanding on this...

Comment: .. it does not help that it is hard to find what "partially initialized module" is (on the level of module-load process(es)); ... with tons of results on how to "fix it", but little on how each of the three import statements actually proceed with the loading/initialization of modules... and whether this is mandated in the Language Reference, or just particular implementation _feature_ which can disappear in a puff.... with the next version of CPython (or other interpreter).

Answer (score 5):

```
import package
import module
```

With `import`, the token must be a module (a file containing Python commands) or a package (a folder in the `sys.path` containing a file `__init__.py`.)

When there are subpackages:

```
import package1.package2.package
import package1.package2.module
```

the requirements for folder (package) or file (module) are the same, but the folder or file must be inside `package2` which must be inside `package1`, and both `package1` and `package2` must contain `__init__.py` files. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

With the `from` style of import:

```
from package1.package2 import package
from package1.package2 import module
```

the package or module enters the namespace of the file containing the `import` statement as `module` (or `package`) instead of `package1.package2.module`. You can always bind to a more convenient name:

```
a = big_package_name.subpackage.even_longer_subpackage_name.function
```

Only the `from` style of import permits you to name a particular function or variable:

```
from package3.module import some_function
```

is allowed, but

```
import package3.module.some_function
```

is not allowed.

Answer (score 5):

This is my directory structure of my current directory:

> ```
> .  
> └─a  
>    └─b  
>      └─c
> ```

1. The `import` statement remembers **all intermediate names**.
   These names **have to be** qualified:

   ```
   In[1]: import a.b.c

   In[2]: a
   Out[2]: <module 'a' (namespace)>

   In[3]: a.b
   Out[3]: <module 'a.b' (namespace)>

   In[4]: a.b.c
   Out[4]: <module 'a.b.c' (namespace)>
   ```
2. The `from ... import ...` statement remembers **only the imported name**.
   This name **must not** be qualified:

   ```
   In[1]: from a.b import c

   In[2]: a
   NameError: name 'a' is not defined

   In[2]: a.b
   NameError: name 'a' is not defined

   In[3]: a.b.c
   NameError: name 'a' is not defined

   In[4]: c
   Out[4]: <module 'a.b.c' (namespace)>
   ```

---

- *Note:* Of course, I restarted my Python console between steps 1 and 2.

Answer (score 4):

To add to what people have said about `from x import *`: besides making it more difficult to tell where names came from, this throws off code checkers like Pylint.  They will report those names as undefined variables.

Answer (score 4):

My own answer to this depends mostly on first, how many different modules I'll be using.  If i'm only going to use one or two, I'll often use **`from`** ... **`import`** since it makes for fewer keystrokes in the rest of the file, but if I'm going to make use of many different modules, I prefer just **`import`** because that means that each module reference is self-documenting.  I can see where each symbol comes from without having to hunt around.

Usuaully I prefer the self documenting style of plain import and only change to from.. import when the number of times I have to type the module name grows above 10 to 20, even if there's only one module being imported.

Answer (score 3):

There have been many answers, but none have mentioned testing (with `unittest` or `pytest`).

## tl;dr

Use `import foo` for external modules to simplify testing.

## The Hard Way

Importing classes/functions (`from foo import bar`) individually from a module makes red-green-refactor cycles tedious. For example, if my file looks like

```
# my_module.py

from foo import bar


class Thing:
    def do_thing(self):
        bar('do a thing')
```

and my test is

```
# test_my_module.py

from unittest.mock import patch
import my_module


patch.object(my_module, 'bar')
def test_do_thing(mock_bar):
    my_module.Thing().do_thing()
    mock_bar.assert_called_with('do a thing')
```

At first glance, this seems great. But what happens if I want to implement `Thing` class in a different file? My structure would have to change like this...

```
# my_module.py

from tools import Thing


def do_thing():
    Thing().do_thing()


# tools.py

from foo import bar


class Thing:
    def do_thing(self):
        bar('do a thing')


# test_my_module.py

from unittest.mock import patch
import my_module
import tools  # Had to import implementation file...


patch.object(tools, 'bar')  # Changed patch
def test_do_thing(mock_bar):
    my_module.do_thing()  # Changed test (expected)
    mock_bar.assert_called_with('do a thing')
```

Unfortunately, since I used `from foo import bar`, I need to update my patch to reference the `tools` module. Essentially, since my test knows too much about implementation, much more than expected needs to be changed to do this refactor.

## The Better Approach

Using `import foo`, my tests can ignore how the module is implemented and simply patch the whole module.

```
# my_module.py

from tools import Thing


def do_thing():
    Thing().do_thing()


# tools.py

import foo


class Thing:
    def do_thing(self):
        foo.bar('do a thing')  # Specify 'bar' is from 'foo' module


# test_my_module.py

from unittest.mock import patch
import my_module


patch('foo')  # Patch entire foo module
def test_do_thing(mock_foo):
    my_module.do_thing()  # Changed test (expected)
    mock_foo.bar.assert_called_with('do a thing')
```

The less implementation details your tests know, the better. That way, if you come up with a better solution (use classes instead of functions, use additional files to separate ideas, etc.), less needs to be changed in your tests to accommodate the refactor.

Answer (score 2):

One of the significant difference I found out which *surprisingly* no-one has talked about is that using plain *import* you can access `private variable` and `private functions` from the imported module, which isn't possible with *from-import* statement.

[image]

Code in image:

## setting.py

```
public_variable = 42
_private_variable = 141
def public_function():
    print("I'm a public function! yay!")
def _private_function():
    print("Ain't nobody accessing me from another module...usually")
```

## plain_importer.py

```
import settings
print (settings._private_variable)
print (settings.public_variable)
settings.public_function()
settings._private_function()

# Prints:
# 141
# 42
# I'm a public function! yay!
# Ain't nobody accessing me from another module...usually
```

## from_importer.py

```
from settings import *
#print (_private_variable) #doesn't work
print (public_variable)
public_function()
#_private_function()   #doesn't work
```

Answer (score 1):

As *Jan Wrobel* mentions, one aspect of the different imports is in which way the imports are disclosed.

Module **mymath**

```py
from math import gcd
...
```

Use of **mymath**:

```
import mymath
mymath.gcd(30, 42)  # will work though maybe not expected
```

If I imported `gcd` only for internal use, not to disclose it to users of `mymath`, this can be inconvenient. I have this pretty often, and in most cases I want to "keep my modules clean".

Apart from the proposal of *Jan Wrobel* to obscure this a bit more by using `import math` instead, I have started to hide imports from disclosure by using a leading underscore:

```
# for instance...
from math import gcd as _gcd
# or...
import math as _math
```

In larger projects this "best practice" allows my to exactly control what is disclosed to subsequent imports and what isn't. This keeps my modules clean and pays back at a certain size of project.

Answer (score 1):

since many people answered here but i am just trying my best :)

1. `import module` is best when you don't know which item you have to import from `module`. In this way it may be difficult to debug when problem raises because
   you don't know which item have problem.
2. `form module import <foo>` is best when you know which item you require to import and also helpful in more controlling using importing specific item according to your need. Using this way debugging may be easy because you know which item you imported.

Answer (score 0):

Import Module - You don't need additional efforts to fetch another thing from module. It has disadvantages such as redundant typing

Module Import From - Less typing &More control over which items of a module can be accessed.To use a new item from the module you have to update your import statement.

Answer (score 0):

There are some builtin modules that contain mostly bare functions ([base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html), [math](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html), [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html), [shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html), [sys](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html), [time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html), ...) and it is definitely a good practice to have these bare functions *bound* to some namespace and thus improve the readability of your code. Consider how more difficult is to understand the meaning of these functions without their namespace:

```py
copysign(foo, bar)
monotonic()
copystat(foo, bar)
```

than when they are bound to some module:

```py
math.copysign(foo, bar)
time.monotonic()
shutil.copystat(foo, bar)
```

Sometimes you even need the namespace to avoid conflicts between different modules ([json.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load) vs. [pickle.load](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.load))

---

On the other hand there are some modules that contain mostly classes ([configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html), [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html), [tempfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html), [zipfile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html), ...) and many of them make their class names self-explanatory enough:

```py
configparser.RawConfigParser()
datetime.DateTime()
email.message.EmailMessage()
tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
zipfile.ZipFile()
```

so there can be a debate whether using these classes with the additional module namespace in your code adds some new information or just lengthens the code.

Answer (score 0):

I was answering a similar question post but the poster deleted it before i could post. Here is one example to illustrate the differences.

Python libraries may have one or more files (modules). For exmaples,

```
package1
  |-- __init__.py
```

or

```
package2
  |-- __init__.py
  |-- module1.py
  |-- module2.py
```

We can define python functions or classes inside *any* of the files based design requirements.

Let's define

1. `func1()` in  `__init__.py` under `mylibrary1`, and
2. `foo()` in `module2.py` under `mylibrary2`.

We can access `func1()` using one of these methods

```
import package1

package1.func1()
```

or

```
import package1 as my

my.func1()
```

or

```
from package1 import func1

func1()
```

or

```
from package1 import *

func1()
```

We can use one of these methods to access `foo()`:

```
import package2.module2

package2.module2.foo()
```

or

```
import package2.module2 as mod2

mod2.foo()
```

or

```
from package2 import module2

module2.foo()
```

or

```
from package2 import module2 as mod2

mod2.foo()
```

or

```
from package2.module2 import *

foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

#### In simple words, this is all about programmer convenience. At the core level, they simply import all functionality of the module.

**`import module`**: When you use `import module` then to use methods of this module you have to write `module.method()`. Every time you use any method or property then you have to refer to the module.

**`from module import all`**: When you use `from module import all` than to use methods of this module you just have to write `method()` without referring to the module.

Answer (score 0):

There is a crucial aspect of these imports that @ahfx already mentioned, namely the internals of the process of loading modules. This pops up if your system needs to use circular imports (e.g. you want to make use of dependency injection in some popular http frameworks). In such cases the `from {module} import {function}` appears much more aggressive with its requirements on how the loading process proceeds. Let us take the example:

```
#m1.py:
print('--start-m1--')
from m2 import *    # form does not matter; just need to force import of m2
print('--mid-m1--')

def do1(x):
    print(x)

print('--end-m1--')
```

importing

```
#m2.py
print('--start-m2--')

# from m1 import *      # A
# from m1 import do1    # B
# import m1             # C
                        # D -- no import of "do1" at all
                        
print('--mid-m2--')

def do2(x):
    m1.do1(x)

print('--end-m2--')
```

run via

```
#main.py:
from m1 import do1
do1('ok')
```

Of all the import possibilities in `m2.py` (A,B,C,D), the `from {module} import {function}` is *the only one* that actually crashes the load process, leading to the infamous (CPython 3.10.6)

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'do1' from partially initialized module 'm1' 
(most likely due to a circular import)
```

While I cannot say why this happens, it appears that the `from ... import ...` statement puts a more stringent requirement on "how far" the module in question is already in its initialization process.