# How to load all modules in a folder?

Tags: python, python-import

Could someone provide me with a good way of importing a whole directory of modules?
I have a structure like this:

```
/Foo
    bar.py
    spam.py
    eggs.py
```

I tried just converting it to a package by adding `__init__.py` and doing `from Foo import *` but it didn't work the way I had hoped.

Comment: Can you define "didn't work"? What happened?  What error message did you get?

Comment: Is this Pythonic or recommended?

["Explicit is better than implicit."](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id3)

Comment: Explicit is indeed better. But would you really like to address these annoying 'not found' messages everytime you add a new module. I think that if you have a package directory containing many small module-functions, then this is the nicest way to go about it. My assumptions are: 1. module are rather simple 2. you use the package for code tidiness

Comment: Note that most (all?) answers on this page will not give you autocomplete in some IDEs and give errors in some linters (they won't "know" what the module is exporting since they don't execute the code). If you're writing a public package and want good 'developer experience', I believe manually declaring what you export is the only way.

Answer (score 496, accepted):

List all python (`.py`) files in the current folder and put them as `__all__` variable in `__init__.py`

```
from os.path import dirname, basename, isfile, join
import glob
modules = glob.glob(join(dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [ basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if isfile(f) and not f.endswith('__init__.py')]
```

Comment: Basically so I can drop python files into a directory with no further configuration and have them be executed by a script running somewhere else.

Comment: @NiallDouglas this answer is for a specific question which OP asked, he  didn't have a zip file and pyc files can be included easily, and you are forgetting .pyd or .so libs etc too

Comment: True, the OP didn't *ask* for running inside zip support, however he did appear to be asking for boilerplate code which would import the contents of a directory. That boilerplate ought to cope with most common situations - it's not hard, just use pkgutil, not os.listdir(), like the other poster below.

Comment: The only thing i would add is `if not os.path.basename(f).startswith('_')` or at the very least `if not f.endswith('__init__.py')` to the end of the list comprehension

Comment: If you have installed 'path.py' (pip install path.py), you can use `__all__ = [f.namebase for f in path(__file__).parent.glob('*.py')]`, which I think looks cleaner. I'm also in agreement that `__init__.py` should be filtered from the list.

Comment: `os.listdir()` is a good alternative to `glob.glob()`: maybe subjective, but IMHO is a bit more standard/readable way to get files in a dir. Or `os.walk()` if you want recursion

Comment: To make it more robust, also make sure `os.path.isfile(f)` is `True`. That would filter out broken symlinks and directories like `somedir.py/` (corner-case, I admit, but still...)

Comment: How can I add the filter @MestreLion? I see no place for if statement in the code above...

Comment: @TomášZato added if condition to list comprehension

Comment: Add `from . import *` after setting `__all__` if you want submodules to be available using `.` (e.g. as `module.submodule1`, `module.submodule2`, etc.).

Comment: I check again today and it seems not working any more https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python#comment75517378_1057446

Comment: To be crossplatform you want to use `os.path.join()` to construct your path, in case the `os.path.sep` isn't `'/'` on the user's troublemaking OS (like Windows): `modules = glob.glob(os.path.join(dirname(__file__), '*.py'))`

Comment: @EvanFosmark not exactly, since if the script is running, the files already have been imported. But great point, if the file is dropped on a server, maybe no one will notice when restarting the app.

Comment: `__all__ = [f for f in glob.glob(__file__.replace('__init__', '*[!_*]'))]`

Answer (score 159):

Add the `__all__` Variable to `__init__.py` containing:

```
__all__ = ["bar", "spam", "eggs"]
```

See also http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Yes, yes, but is there any way of having it be dynamic?

Comment: Combination of `os.listdir()`, some filtering, stripping of `.py` extension and `__all__`.

Comment: Not working for me as sample code here https://github.com/namgivu/python-import-all/blob/master/error_app.py . Maybe I miss something there?

Comment: I found out myself - to use the variable/object defined in those modules, we have to use the full reference path e.g. `moduleName.varName` ref. https://stackoverflow.com/a/710603/248616

Comment: @NamGVU: This code in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14428820/355230) to a related question will import all the public sub-modules' names into the the package's namespace.

Answer (score 78):

Update in 2017: you probably want to use [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/library/importlib.html) instead.

Make the Foo directory a package by adding an `__init__.py`. In that `__init__.py` add:

```
import bar
import eggs
import spam
```

Since you want it dynamic (which may or may not be a good idea), list all py-files with list dir and import them with something like this:

```
import os
for module in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)):
    if module == '__init__.py' or module[-3:] != '.py':
        continue
    __import__(module[:-3], locals(), globals())
del module
```

Then, from your code do this:

```
import Foo
```

You can now access the modules with

```
Foo.bar
Foo.eggs
Foo.spam
```

etc. `from Foo import *` is not a good idea for several reasons, including name clashes and making it hard to analyze the code.

Comment: Not bad, but don't forget that you can import .pyc and .pyo files too.

Comment: tbh, i find `__import__` hackish, i think it would be better to add the names to `__all__` and then put `from . import *` at the bottom of the script

Comment: I think this is nicer than the glob version.

Comment: Instead of del, you can do `import os as _os`

Comment: `__import__` is not for general uses, it  used by `interpreter`, use `importlib.import_module()` instead.

Comment: importlib didn't exist when I wrote this answer, and __import__ works just fine. But yes, you can use importlib as well in 2.7 and later.

Comment: what is `del module` for, and why is it outside the for-loop block?

Comment: To delete the module variable, which is otherwise keeping a reference to the last module name and to be honest I don't know why I put it in there, it's not really very useful. In any case, this answer is old, use importlib instead. :-)

Comment: The first example was very helpful, thanks! Under Python 3.6.4 I had to do `from . import eggs` etc. in the `__init__.py` before Python could import. With only `import eggs` I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'eggs'` when trying to `import Foo` in the `main.py` in the directory above.

Comment: What is this difference between this and __all__=['bar,'eggs',ham']? 

It seems cleaner and more in keeping with the original intention of the import statement.  Is there anything else?

Comment: The idea here is to load all modules in a folder, which means a module will be loaded simply if it's added to the folder, without changing any code.

I agree it's generally a thing to avoid.

Comment: Please define 'today'. I assume you mean from a particular version of Python? Which? Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelScheper Any version of Python that includes `importlib`. And if your version doesn't, please upgrade.

Comment: This answer was very helpful! But it didn't work right out of the box for some reason on Py3.5.6.  I had to append the `.` to the beginning of the `module` string for this to work , otherwise it gave a "no module named <filename>` ImportError.  Also, when switching to `importlib.import_module(  )` you have to add the argument `importlib.import_module( modulebase, parent=__name__ )` for it to go into the module's namespace.  Let me know if you want a full code example.

Answer (score 55):

### Python, include all files under a directory:

For newbies who just can't get it to work who need their hands held.

1. Make a folder /home/el/foo and make a file `main.py` under /home/el/foo  Put this code in there:

   ```
   from hellokitty import *
   spam.spamfunc()
   ham.hamfunc()
   ```
2. Make a directory `/home/el/foo/hellokitty`
3. Make a file `__init__.py` under `/home/el/foo/hellokitty` and put this code in there:

   ```
   __all__ = ["spam", "ham"]
   ```
4. Make two python files: `spam.py` and `ham.py` under `/home/el/foo/hellokitty`
5. Define a function inside spam.py:

   ```
   def spamfunc():
     print("Spammity spam")
   ```
6. Define a function inside ham.py:

   ```
   def hamfunc():
     print("Upgrade from baloney")
   ```
7. Run it:

   ```
   el@apollo:/home/el/foo$ python main.py 
   spammity spam
   Upgrade from baloney
   ```

Comment: Not just for newbies, but also experienced Python devs who like clear answers. Thanks.

Comment: But using `import *` is considered bad Python coding practice.  How do you do this without that?

Comment: @RachaelBlake I think it's considered bad practice in cases where you're importing all the functions from one namespace into the global namespace.  Because you could have overlaps there.  In this situation, notice that the namespace of the imported filenames is required (I.E., `spam.spamfunc()`,).  `spamfunc` and `hamfunc` aren't in the global namespace, so there's no potential for overlap.

Answer (score 47):

Expanding on Mihail's answer, I believe the non-hackish way (as in, not handling the file paths directly) is the following:

1. create an empty `__init__.py` file under `Foo/`
2. Execute

```py
import pkgutil
import sys


def load_all_modules_from_dir(dirname):
    for importer, package_name, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([dirname]):
        full_package_name = '%s.%s' % (dirname, package_name)
        if full_package_name not in sys.modules:
            module = importer.find_module(package_name
                        ).load_module(full_package_name)
            print module


load_all_modules_from_dir('Foo')
```

You'll get:

```
<module 'Foo.bar' from '/home/.../Foo/bar.pyc'>
<module 'Foo.spam' from '/home/.../Foo/spam.pyc'>
```

Comment: This is most of the way there to a correct answer - it handles ZIP archives, but doesn't write __init__ nor import. See automodinit below.

Comment: Another thing: the above example doesn't check sys.modules to see if the module is already loaded. Without that check the above will load the module a second time :)

Comment: When I run load_all_modules_from_dir('Foo/bar') with your code I get "RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'Foo/bar' not found while handling absolute import" - to suppress this, I have to set full_package_name = '.'.join(dirname.split(os.path.sep) + package_name]) and also import Foo.bar

Comment: Those `RuntimeWarning` messages can also be avoided by not using full_package_name at all: `importer.find_module(package_name).load_module(package_name)`.

Comment: The `RuntimeWarning` errors can also be avoided (in an arguably ugly way) by importing the parent (AKA dirname).  One way to do that is - `if dirname not in sys.modules: pkgutil.find_loader(dirname).load_module(dirname)`.  Of course, that  only works if `dirname` is a single-component relative path; no slashes.  Personally, I prefer @Artfunkel's approach of using the base package_name instead.

Answer (score 20):

I know I'm updating a quite old post, and I tried using `automodinit`, but found out it's setup process is broken for python3. So, based on Luca's answer, I came up with a simpler answer - which might not work with .zip - to this issue, so I figured I should share it here:

within the `__init__.py` module from `yourpackage`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, pkgutil
__all__ = list(module for _, module, _ in pkgutil.iter_modules([os.path.dirname(__file__)]))
```

and within another package below `yourpackage`:

```
from yourpackage import *
```

Then you'll have all the modules that are placed within the package loaded, and if you write a new module, it'll be automagically imported as well. Of course, use that kind of things with care, with great powers comes great responsibilities.

Answer (score 16):

I got tired of this problem myself, so I wrote a package called automodinit to fix it. You can get it from http://pypi.python.org/pypi/automodinit/.

Usage is like this:

1. Include the `automodinit` package into your `setup.py` dependencies.
2. Replace all __init__.py files like this:

```
__all__ = ["I will get rewritten"]
# Don't modify the line above, or this line!
import automodinit
automodinit.automodinit(__name__, __file__, globals())
del automodinit
# Anything else you want can go after here, it won't get modified.
```

That's it! From now on importing a module will set __all__ to
a list of .py[co] files in the module and will also import each
of those files as though you had typed:

```
for x in __all__: import x
```

Therefore the effect of "from M import *" matches exactly "import M".

`automodinit` is happy running from inside ZIP archives and is therefore ZIP safe.

Niall

Comment: pip can't download automodinit because there's nothing uploaded on pypi for it.

Comment: Thanks for the bug report on github. I've fixed this in v0.13. Niall

Answer (score 10):

```
import pkgutil
__path__ = pkgutil.extend_path(__path__, __name__)
for imp, module, ispackage in pkgutil.walk_packages(path=__path__, prefix=__name__+'.'):
  __import__(module)
```

Answer (score 9):

I have also encountered this problem and this was my solution:

```
import os

def loadImports(path):
    files = os.listdir(path)
    imps = []

    for i in range(len(files)):
        name = files[i].split('.')
        if len(name) > 1:
            if name[1] == 'py' and name[0] != '__init__':
               name = name[0]
               imps.append(name)

    file = open(path+'__init__.py','w')

    toWrite = '__all__ = '+str(imps)

    file.write(toWrite)
    file.close()
```

This function creates a file (in the provided folder) named `__init__.py`, which contains an `__all__` variable that holds every module in the folder.

For example, I have a folder named `Test`
which contains:

```
Foo.py
Bar.py
```

So in the script I want the modules to be imported into I will write:

```
loadImports('Test/')
from Test import *
```

This will import everything from `Test` and the `__init__.py` file in `Test` will now contain:

```
__all__ = ['Foo','Bar']
```

Answer (score 6):

When `from . import *` isn't good enough, this is an improvement over the [answer by ted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59054776/). Specifically, the use of `__all__` is not necessary with this approach.

```py
"""Import all modules that exist in the current directory."""
# Ref https://stackoverflow.com/a/60861023/
from importlib import import_module
from pathlib import Path

for f in Path(__file__).parent.glob("*.py"):
    module_name = f.stem
    if (not module_name.startswith("_")) and (module_name not in globals()):
        import_module(f".{module_name}", __package__)
    del f, module_name
del import_module, Path
```

Note that `module_name not in globals()` is intended to avoid reimporting the module if it's already imported, as this can risk cyclic imports.

Comment: Is the line line really needed if this is encapsulated in a function?

Comment: @shay__ The `del` lines are not needed if the snippet is in a function.

Answer (score 5):

[Anurag Uniyal answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1057534/281545) with suggested improvements!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import glob

all_list = list()
for f in glob.glob(os.path.dirname(__file__)+"/*.py"):
    if os.path.isfile(f) and not os.path.basename(f).startswith('_'):
        all_list.append(os.path.basename(f)[:-3])

__all__ = all_list
```

Answer (score 5):

This is the best way i've found so far:

```
from os.path import dirname, join, isdir, abspath, basename
from glob import glob
pwd = dirname(__file__)
for x in glob(join(pwd, '*.py')):
    if not x.startswith('__'):
        __import__(basename(x)[:-3], globals(), locals())
```

Comment: `abspath` and `isdir` is unused ;)

Answer (score 5):

Using [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) the only thing you've got to add is

```
from importlib import import_module
from pathlib import Path

__all__ = [
    import_module(f".{f.stem}", __package__)
    for f in Path(__file__).parent.glob("*.py")
    if "__" not in f.stem
]
del import_module, Path
```

Comment: This leads to a legitimate mypy issue: `error: Type of __all__ must be "Sequence[str]", not "List[Module]"`. Defining `__all__` is not required if this `import_module` based approach is used.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a module for that, which doesn't rely on `__init__.py` (or any other auxiliary file) and makes me type only the following two lines:

```
import importdir
importdir.do("Foo", globals())
```

Feel free to re-use or contribute: http://gitlab.com/aurelien-lourot/importdir

Answer (score 4):

Anurag's example with a couple of corrections:

```
import os, glob

modules = glob.glob(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "*.py"))
__all__ = [os.path.basename(f)[:-3] for f in modules if not f.endswith("__init__.py")]
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd like to add to [Anurag Uniyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6946/anurag-uniyal)'s answer.
You can make it even simpler and get rid of a lot of the imports.
Contents of the __init__.py file:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import dirname
__all__ = [i[:-3] for i in listdir(dirname(__file__)) if not i.startswith('__') and i.endswith('.py')]
```

Answer (score 3):

See that your `__init__.py` defines `__all__`. The [modules - packages](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/modules.html#packages) doc says

> The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path. In the simplest case, `__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable, described later.
>
> ...
>
> The only solution is for the package author to provide an explicit index of the package. The import statement uses the following convention: if a package’s `__init__.py` code defines a list named `__all__`, it is taken to be the list of module names that should be imported when from package import * is encountered. It is up to the package author to keep this list up-to-date when a new version of the package is released. Package authors may also decide not to support it, if they don’t see a use for importing * from their package. For example, the file `sounds/effects/__init__.py` could contain the following code:
>
> `__all__ = ["echo", "surround", "reverse"]`
>
> This would mean that `from sound.effects import *` would import the three named submodules of the sound package.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the pkgutil module from the standard library. It will let you do exactly what you want as long as you have an `__init__.py` file in the directory. The `__init__.py` file can be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, with which you do not have to write the file name. Just add this code snippet to your `__init__.py`

```
from inspect import isclass
from pkgutil import iter_modules
from pathlib import Path
from importlib import import_module

# iterate through the modules in the current package
package_dir = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
for (_, module_name, _) in iter_modules([package_dir]):

    # import the module and iterate through its attributes
    module = import_module(f"{__name__}.{module_name}")
    for attribute_name in dir(module):
        attribute = getattr(module, attribute_name)

        if isclass(attribute):            
            # Add the class to this package's variables
            globals()[attribute_name] = attribute
```

[Source](https://julienharbulot.com/python-dynamical-import.html)

Answer (score 1):

None of the solutions was working for me in Python 3.9.5, Flask 2.2.2, the module being a directory 2 levels down the cwd.
This is my solution:

```
import importlib
import pathlib
import re

path = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()
names = [x.name[:-3] for x in path.iterdir() if x.is_file() and re.search("^[a-z]*\.py$", x.name)]
for name in names:
    importlib.import_module(f".{name}", __name__)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just import them by [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) and add them to `__all__` (`add` action is optional) in recurse in the `__init__.py` of package.

```
/Foo
    bar.py
    spam.py
    eggs.py
    __init__.py

# __init__.py
import os
import importlib
pyfile_extes = ['py', ]
__all__ = [importlib.import_module('.%s' % filename, __package__) for filename in [os.path.splitext(i)[0] for i in os.listdir(os.path.dirname(__file__)) if os.path.splitext(i)[1] in pyfile_extes] if not filename.startswith('__')]
del os, importlib, pyfile_extes
```

Comment: Where is pyfile_extes defined?

Comment: sorry for missing it, now fixed. It is the extention of python file you want to import, usually just `py`

Answer (score 0):

I had a nested directory structure i.e. I had multiple directories inside the main directory that contained the python modules.

I added the following script to my `__init__.py` file to import all the modules

```
import glob, re, os 

module_parent_directory = "path/to/the/directory/containing/__init__.py/file"

owd = os.getcwd()
if not owd.endswith(module_parent_directory): os.chdir(module_parent_directory)

module_paths = glob.glob("**/*.py", recursive = True)

for module_path in module_paths:
    if not re.match( ".*__init__.py$", module_path):
        import_path = module_path[:-3]
        import_path = import_path.replace("/", ".")
        exec(f"from .{import_path} import *")

os.chdir(owd)
```

Probably not the best way to achieve this, but I couldn't make anything else work for me.