# Import all the modules in a directory

Tags: python, module

Is there any way to import all modules in the current directory, and return a list of them?

For example, for the directory with:

- mod.py
- mod2.py
- mod3.py

It will give you `[<module 'mod'>, <module 'mod2'>, <module 'mod3'>]`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Loading all modules in a folder in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1057431/loading-all-modules-in-a-folder-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

I think I've got your idea.

Try the following:

```
import glob
modules = []
for module_name in glob.glob("*.py"):
    modules.append(__import__(module_name[:-3]))
```

This way you get a list of `module` objects and don't pollute the global namespace.

Comment: To make it work, you need to get rid of the `.py` suffixes.

Comment: @bereal Thanks a lot! That is quite easy, however.