# python eval('import foo') raises SyntaxError

Tags: python, eval

My code structure:

```
/foo
    __init__.py
    bar.py
```

**init**.py

```
import bar
eval("import bar")
```

It raises `SyntaxError` when execute the second line.

```
>>> import foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "foo/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    eval('import bar')
  File "<string>", line 1
    import bar
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am confused because I would expect behaviors of these codes should be the same.

Comment: `eval` expects an expression, `import` is a statement. That said, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to import modules at runtime like [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083140/import-all-the-modules-in-a-directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083140/import-all-the-modules-in-a-directory).

Comment: @gzc Then what is wrong with the answers of that question?

Comment: @phihag `eval` cannot work.

Comment: @gzc Sorry, can you elaborate? [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16495561/35070) does not use `eval`, but still manages to import all modules in a directory.

Comment: is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17136772/eval-to-import-a-module

Comment: Why are you doing `eval("import bar")` in the first place?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Just for demo.

Comment: @phihag Yes, It works if `__import__('foo.bar')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `exec` instead if you intend to import the module:

```
exec("import bar")
```