# How do I import other Python files?

Tags: python, python-import, python-module, python-packaging

How do I import files in Python? I want to import:

1. a file (e.g. `file.py`)
2. a folder
3. a file dynamically at runtime, based on user input
4. one specific part of a file (e.g. a single function)

Comment: See Also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663076/python-best-way-to-add-to-sys-path-relative-to-the-current-running-script

Comment: If A and B are two files within the same directory, in python 3.x, and you want to import A's content, `import A` will not work. We have to use `from current_directory_name import *`, or `from current_directory_name import THINGS_YOU_WANT_TO_IMPORT` . Play around a little bit for importing from  different directory

Comment: import os
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/peter/")
from secret_key import *
os.environ['OPENAI_API_KEY'] = openapi_key

Answer (score 552, accepted):

[`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib) was added to Python 3 to programmatically import a module.

```python
import importlib

moduleName = input('Enter module name:')
importlib.import_module(moduleName)
```

The .py extension should be removed from `moduleName`. The function also defines a `package` argument for relative imports.

In python 2.x:

- Just `import file` without the .py extension
- A folder can be marked as a package, by adding an empty `__init__.py` file
- You can use the `__import__` function, which takes the module name (without extension) as a string extension

```python
pmName = input('Enter module name:')
pm = __import__(pmName)
print(dir(pm))
```

Type `help(__import__)` for more details.

Comment: If you add an `import filename` to the __init__.py then you can import the module directly as the folder name.

Comment: from `help(__import__)`: `Because this function is meant for use by the Python
    interpreter and not for general use it is better to use
    importlib.import_module() to programmatically import a module.`

Comment: What if it's not a package but just a script file?

Comment: For importing a script file in the same path (maybe it would also work for a script file in a Python search path), `import filenamenoext` works just fine for me, with Python 3.4.8.

Comment: Is it still accurate in 2019? Is it python3 or 2?

Comment: Importing in Python is a bizarre mess. It should be possible to import any function from any file, with a simple line of code providing the path (absolute or relative, hard-coded or stored in a variable) to the file. Python, just do it!

Comment: what if it does not have a .py extension ?  It may be a common config file since var = "x" is commonly shared syntax.

Comment: What is the advantage of "importlib" instead of "import"?

Answer (score 1469):

### There are many ways to import a python file, all with their pros and cons.

Don't just hastily pick the first import strategy that works for you or else you'll have to rewrite the codebase later on when you find it doesn't meet your needs.

I'll start out explaining the easiest example #1, then I'll move toward the most professional and robust example #7

**Example 1, Import a python module with python interpreter:**

1. Put this in /home/el/foo/fox.py:

   ```
   def what_does_the_fox_say():
     print("vixens cry")
   ```
2. Get into the python interpreter:

   ```
   el@apollo:/home/el/foo$ python
   Python 2.7.3 (default, Sep 26 2013, 20:03:06) 
   >>> import fox
   >>> fox.what_does_the_fox_say()
   vixens cry
   >>>
   ```

   You imported fox through the python interpreter, invoked the python function `what_does_the_fox_say()` from within fox.py.

**Example 2, Use `execfile` or ([`exec` in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6357361/55075)) in a script to execute the other python file in place:**

1. Put this in /home/el/foo2/mylib.py:

   ```
   def moobar():
     print("hi")
   ```
2. Put this in /home/el/foo2/main.py:

   ```
   execfile("/home/el/foo2/mylib.py")
   moobar()
   ```
3. run the file:

   ```
   el@apollo:/home/el/foo$ python main.py
   hi
   ```

   The function moobar was imported from mylib.py and made available in main.py

**Example 3, Use from ... import ... functionality:**

1. Put this in /home/el/foo3/chekov.py:

   ```
   def question():
     print "where are the nuclear wessels?"
   ```
2. Put this in /home/el/foo3/main.py:

   ```
   from chekov import question
   question()
   ```
3. Run it like this:

   ```
   el@apollo:/home/el/foo3$ python main.py 
   where are the nuclear wessels?
   ```

   If you defined other functions in chekov.py, they would not be available unless you `import *`

**Example 4, Import riaa.py if it's in a different file location from where it is imported**

1. Put this in /home/el/foo4/stuff/riaa.py:

   ```
   def watchout():
     print "computers are transforming into a noose and a yoke for humans"
   ```
2. Put this in /home/el/foo4/main.py:

   ```
   import sys 
   import os
   sys.path.append(os.path.abspath("/home/el/foo4/stuff"))
   from riaa import *
   watchout()
   ```
3. Run it:

   ```
   el@apollo:/home/el/foo4$ python main.py 
   computers are transforming into a noose and a yoke for humans
   ```

   That imports everything in the foreign file from a different directory.

**Example 5, use `os.system("python yourfile.py")`**

```
import os
os.system("python yourfile.py")
```

**Example 6, import your file via piggybacking the python startuphook:**

**Update:** This example used to work for both python2 and 3, but now only works for python2.  python3 got rid of this user startuphook feature set because it was abused by low-skill python library writers, using it to impolitely inject their code into the global namespace, before all user-defined programs.  If you want this to work for python3, you'll have to get more creative.  If I tell you how to do it, python developers will disable that feature set as well, so you're on your own.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/user.html

Put this code into your home directory in `~/.pythonrc.py`

```
class secretclass:
    def secretmessage(cls, myarg):
        return myarg + " is if.. up in the sky, the sky"
    secretmessage = classmethod( secretmessage )

    def skycake(cls):
        return "cookie and sky pie people can't go up and "
    skycake = classmethod( skycake )
```

Put this code into your main.py (can be anywhere):

```
import user
msg = "The only way skycake tates good" 
msg = user.secretclass.secretmessage(msg)
msg += user.secretclass.skycake()
print(msg + " have the sky pie! SKYCAKE!")
```

Run it, you should get this:

```
$ python main.py
The only way skycake tates good is if.. up in the sky, 
the skycookie and sky pie people can't go up and  have the sky pie! 
SKYCAKE!
```

If you get an error here: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'user'` then it means you're using python3, startuphooks are disabled there by default.

Credit for this jist goes to: https://github.com/docwhat/homedir-examples/blob/master/python-commandline/.pythonrc.py  Send along your up-boats.

**Example 7, Most Robust: Import files in python with the bare import command:**

1. Make a new directory `/home/el/foo5/`
2. Make a new directory `/home/el/foo5/herp`
3. Make an empty file named `__init__.py` under herp:

   ```
   el@apollo:/home/el/foo5/herp$ touch __init__.py
   el@apollo:/home/el/foo5/herp$ ls
   __init__.py
   ```
4. Make a new directory /home/el/foo5/herp/derp
5. Under derp, make another `__init__.py` file:

   ```
   el@apollo:/home/el/foo5/herp/derp$ touch __init__.py
   el@apollo:/home/el/foo5/herp/derp$ ls
   __init__.py
   ```
6. Under /home/el/foo5/herp/derp make a new file called `yolo.py` Put this in there:

   ```
   def skycake():
     print "SkyCake evolves to stay just beyond the cognitive reach of " +
     "the bulk of men. SKYCAKE!!"
   ```
7. The moment of truth, Make the new file `/home/el/foo5/main.py`, put this in there;

   ```
   from herp.derp.yolo import skycake
   skycake()
   ```
8. Run it:

   ```
   el@apollo:/home/el/foo5$ python main.py
   SkyCake evolves to stay just beyond the cognitive reach of the bulk 
   of men. SKYCAKE!!
   ```

   The empty `__init__.py` file communicates to the python interpreter that the developer intends this directory to be an importable package.

If you want to see my post on how to include ALL .py files under a directory see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20753073/445131

Comment: You should also add Example 6: using `__import__(py_file_name)`. 
Amazing guide anyway

Comment: Every time I have an import issue I end up at this question and am always able to solve my problem. If I could upvote this for each time you've helped me, I would.

Comment: What's the big difference between all of these, and why is one better than any other? For example 5, you write "Import files in python with the bare import command," but you also use the (bare?) import command in examples 1, 3 and 4, don't you?

Comment: Hey Eric! I think you got me wrong.. I just wanted to answer HelloGoodbyes question "what's the big difference between all of these" because I too was curious and found the blog entry (which is NOT mine btw) which I thought was helpful for him too...

Comment: Good answer but the fact that you use a different import file as example all the times makes it cumbersome to read.

Comment: @ErikLeschinski, how would you classify and use 'subprocess' call method ? do you think it should be added along side with **method 6**?

Comment: How about having a file which just imports and loads all necessary packages. How could one do that and make the current file aware of all loaded in the other file? Thank You.

Comment: I would like to emphasize that even if you work on Windows, the import is case sensitive. So you cannot have **Module.py** and have in your code **import module**

Comment: **Example 4** creates a file with `.pyc` ending. Who knows how to prevent it from being created? Or it is necessary?

Comment: your opening statement should be a precursor to every popular answer, thanks for this, my analytical code base is a mess, refactoring for the first time.

Comment: Also want to add - it seems packages can't have a dash in the name :\

Comment: To tend towards a more complete list of solutions, I think we could add the following two interactive methods: the `python -m` method (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56345425/7020378)) similar to example 1, and the `PYTHONPATH` method (see [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35998231/7020378)) similar to example 4.

Comment: exec in python3 does not (or does no longer) take a file the way execfile did in python2. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357361/alternative-to-execfile-in-python-3 about how to do something like execfile in python3.

Comment: A few of these things are **not importing**, and this also doesn't touch on relative imports at all.

Answer (score 182):

***First case*** 
You want to import file `A.py` in file `B.py`, these two files are in the same folder, like this:

```
. 
├── A.py 
└── B.py
```

You can do this in file `B.py`:

```
import A
```

or

```
from A import *
```

or

```
from A import THINGS_YOU_WANT_TO_IMPORT_IN_A
```

Then you will be able to use all the functions of file `A.py` in file `B.py`

---

***Second case***
You want to import file `folder/A.py` in file `B.py`, these two files are not in the same folder, like this:

```
.
├── B.py
└── folder
     └── A.py
```

You can do this in file `B.py`:

```
import folder.A
```

or

```
from folder.A import *
```

or

```
from folder.A import THINGS_YOU_WANT_TO_IMPORT_IN_A
```

Then you will be able to use all the functions of file `A.py` in file `B.py`

---

***Summary***

- In the **first case**, file `A.py` is a module that you imports in file `B.py`, you used the syntax `import module_name`.
- In the **second case**, `folder` is the package that contains the module `A.py`, you used the syntax `import package_name.module_name`.

For more info on packages and modules, consult this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7948504/6057480).

Comment: I tried with a little variation and it worked. `from folder_a.script import *` Script.py is under the folder a.

Comment: +1 This is what I was looking for. Couldn't understand other answers but you explained it using the directories.

Comment: What if I want to import a py file that is in the parent directory?

Comment: @bytedev Add `import sys` and
`sys.path.append("..")` to the beginning of the file. According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48341902/6057480  . Tested, working perfectly, after doing this, you will be able to import a py file in the parent directory and still able to import py files in the same directory and sub-directories.

Comment: even within the same directory, in python 3.x, `import A` will not work. We have to use `from current_directory_name import *`, or `from current_directory_name import THINGS_YOU_WANT_TO_IMPORT`

Comment: @ShivamJha I have Python version 3.7.4, and `import A` works well in the case that `A.py` & `B.py` are in the same folder.

Comment: that's then cool for you bro, I am in 3.8.x and it didn't work for me tho.

Comment: @ShivamJha I've tested `python 3.8.3` and it still works (tested on `ubuntu` and `mac`), which can confirm that this problem is not a version issue, read the error message may help. Though I don't know why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Okay, thank you @BohaoLI, I will check it out brother

Comment: @Falaque I've tested 3.8.5 on windows and it works. Just installed this version from Microsoft Store app on windows.

Comment: I am in windows 8.1; I am using python-3.8.5-embed-amd64. but it is not working.

Comment: @Falaque I am in Windows 10.

Comment: Case 1 is not working for me. It is driving me nuts

Comment: Linux, Anaconda, Jupyter - not working.

Comment: @HD2000 Could you please specify the error you encountered?

Comment: in the second case imagine there is a C file beside folder A, or even inside folder2 which is inside the folder. File A can load C correctly when opening it directly. but when I am in B address, I cannot open it. and need to do it like this "from folder.folder2.C import *"
when I am in A folder I load it like "from folder2.C import *"
how to solve this in a way other than adding a "folder." in the beginning of every import?

Comment: @bunNyBug I'm afraid that's impossible. When two python files are not in the same folder, it's impossible for one file to import another file without using the "folder." method.

Comment: What if you want to import a function from B.py to A.py?

Comment: @Sebastián You can do this —-> from B import NAME_OF_THE_FUNCTION (put this line in the first line of A.py)

Answer (score 96):

To import a specific Python file at 'runtime' with a known name:

```
import os
import sys
```

...

```
scriptpath = "../Test/"

# Add the directory containing your module to the Python path (wants absolute paths)
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(scriptpath))

# Do the import
import MyModule
```

Comment: My friend checked this today with no luck - looks like filename should not be there. He used local file in parent directory and "./" worked at the end as if parent directory (..). Fixing problem in post was rejected - probably misunderstanding(?) Print sys.path and compare records if you are not sure...

Answer (score 41):

You do not have many complex methods to import a python file from one folder to another. Just create a **__init__.py** file to declare this folder is a python package and then go to your host file where you want to import just type

`from root.parent.folder.file import variable, class, whatever`

Comment: What if I want a relative path?

Answer (score 27):

[Import doc ..](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_modules.htm) -- Link for reference

The `__init__.py` files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages, this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later on the module search path.

`__init__.py` can just be an empty file, but it can also execute initialization code for the package or set the `__all__` variable.

```python
mydir/spam/__init__.py
mydir/spam/module.py
import spam.module
or
from spam import module
```

Answer (score 24):

```
from file import function_name  ######## Importing specific function
function_name()                 ######## Calling function
```

and

```
import file              ######## Importing whole package
file.function1_name()    ######## Calling function
file.function2_name()    ######## Calling function
```

Here are the two simple ways I have understood by now and make sure your "file.py" file which you want to import as a library is present in your current directory only.

Answer (score 19):

If the function defined is in a file `x.py`:

```py
def greet():
    print('Hello! How are you?')
```

In the file where you are importing the function, write this:

```py
from x import greet
```

This is useful if you do not wish to import all the functions in a file.

Answer (score 10):

Using Python 3.5 or later, you can use [`importlib.util`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) to directly import a `.py` file in an arbitrary location as a module without needing to modify `sys.path`.

```py
import importlib.util
import sys

def load_module(file_name, module_name)
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(module_name, file_name)
    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    sys.modules[module_name] = module
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)
    return module
```

The `file_name` parameter must be a string or a path-like object. The `module_name` parameter is required because all loaded Python modules must have a (dotted) module name (like `sys`, `importlib`, or `importlib.util`), but you can choose any available name you want for this new module.

You can use this function like this:

```py
my_module = load_module("file.py", "mymod")
```

After it has been imported once into the Python process using the `load_module()` function, the module will be importable using the module name given to it.

`file.py`:

```py
print(f"file.py was imported as {__name__}")
```

`one.py`:

```py
print(f"one.py was imported as {__name__}")
load_module("file.py", "mymod")
import two
```

`two.py`:

```py
print(f"two.py was imported as {__name__})")
import mymod
```

Given the files above, you can run the following command to see how `file.py` became importable.

```
$ python3 -m one
one.py was imported as __main__
two.py was imported as two
file.py was imported as mymod
```

This answer is based on the official Python documentation: [`importlib`: Importing a source file directly.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importing-a-source-file-directly)

Answer (score 9):

I'd like to add this note I don't very clearly elsewhere; inside a module/package, when loading from files, the module/package name must be prefixed with the `mymodule`. Imagine `mymodule` being layout like this:

```
/main.py
/mymodule
    /__init__.py
    /somefile.py
    /otherstuff.py
```

When loading `somefile.py`/`otherstuff.py` from `__init__.py` the contents should look like:

```
from mymodule.somefile import somefunc
from mymodule.otherstuff import otherfunc
```

Answer (score 7):

the best way to import .py files is by way of `__init__.py`. the simplest thing to do, is to create an empty file named `__init__.py` in the same directory that your.py file is located.

this [post](http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html) by Mike Grouchy is a great explanation of `__init__.py` and its use for making, importing, and setting up python packages.

Comment: @GhostCat I have updated my response. thanks for the link "it would be preferable".

Comment: And understand that not everyone is living in your timezone.

Comment: You should've posted the contents of Mike Grouchy's post, especially since the link now 404s. https://web.archive.org/web/20190309045451/https://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html

Answer (score 7):

```
import sys
#print(sys.path)
sys.path.append('../input/tokenization')
import tokenization
```

To import any .py file, you can use above code.

First append the path and then import

Note:'../input/tokenization' directory contains tokenization.py file

Answer (score 5):

How I import is import the file and use shorthand of it's name.

```
import DoStuff.py as DS
DS.main()
```

**Don't forget** that your importing file **MUST BE** named with .py extension

Comment: Wouldn't `import DoStuff.py as DS` attempt to import `py` from `DoStuff`?

Comment: That's a deal breaker.  In the extreme I will be embedding PHP to import now,  I don't really need to just import def's. I may want to import "dev only" tracts or common app.cfg files. I just want to be able to substitute code.  Preprocessing it in is a rotten way to do it.

Answer (score 4):

There are couple of ways of including your python script with name abc.py

1. e.g. if your file is called abc.py (import abc)
   Limitation is that your file should be present in the same location where your calling python script is.

> import abc

2. e.g. if your python file is inside the Windows folder. Windows folder is present at the same location where your calling python script is.

> from folder import abc

3. Incase abc.py script is available insider internal_folder which is present inside folder

> from folder.internal_folder import abc

4. As answered by James above, in case your file is at some fixed location

> import os
>   import sys
>   scriptpath = "../Test/MyModule.py"
>   sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(scriptpath))
>   import MyModule

In case your python script gets updated and you don't want to upload - use these statements for auto refresh. Bonus :)

```
%load_ext autoreload 
%autoreload 2
```

Answer (score 4):

This helped me to structure my Python project with [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code).

The problem could be caused when you don't declare `__init__.py` inside the directory. And the directory becomes `implicit namespace package`. Here is a nice summary about [Python imports and project structure](https://dev.to/codemouse92/dead-simple-python-project-structure-and-imports-38c6).

Also if you want to use the Visual Studio Code run button [image: run button] in the top bar with a script which is not inside the main package, you may try to run console from the actual directory.

For example, you want to execute an opened `test_game_item.py` from the tests package and you have Visual Studio Code opened in `omission` (main package) directory:

```
├── omission
│   ├── app.py
│   ├── common
│   │   ├── classproperty.py
│   │   ├── constants.py
│   │   ├── game_enums.py
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── game
│   │   ├── content_loader.py
│   │   ├── game_item.py
│   │   ├── game_round.py
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   └── timer.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── resources
│   └── tests
│       ├── __init__.py
│       ├── test_game_item.py
│       ├── test_game_round_settings.py
│       ├── test_scoreboard.py
│       ├── test_settings.py
│       ├── test_test.py
│       └── test_timer.py
├── pylintrc
├── README.md
└── .gitignore
```

The directory structure is from [[2](https://dev.to/codemouse92/dead-simple-python-project-structure-and-imports-38c6)].

You can try set this:

(Windows) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> → *Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)*.

Add this line to your **user settings**:

```
"python.terminal.executeInFileDir": true
```

A more comprehensive answer also for other systems is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65835091/10601708).

Answer (score 3):

In case the **module** you want to import is **not in a sub-directory**, then try the following and run `app.py` from the deepest common parent directory:

Directory Structure:

```
/path/to/common_dir/module/file.py
/path/to/common_dir/application/app.py
/path/to/common_dir/application/subpath/config.json
```

In `app.py`, append path of client to sys.path:

```
import os, sys, inspect

sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
from module.file import MyClass
instance = MyClass()
```

Optional (If you load e.g. configs) (Inspect seems to be the most robust one for my use cases)

```
# Get dirname from inspect module
filename = inspect.getframeinfo(inspect.currentframe()).filename
dirname = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(filename))
MY_CONFIG = os.path.join(dirname, "subpath/config.json")
```

Run

```
user@host:/path/to/common_dir$ python3 application/app.py
```

This solution works for me in cli, as well as PyCharm.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did to call a function from a python file, that is flexible for me to call any functions.

```
import os, importlib, sys

def callfunc(myfile, myfunc, *args):
    pathname, filename = os.path.split(myfile)
    sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(pathname))
    modname = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    mymod = importlib.import_module(modname)
    result = getattr(mymod, myfunc)(*args)
    return result

result = callfunc("pathto/myfile.py", "myfunc", arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: How is making a new function better than using the function directly?

Comment: @qwr  The new function callfunc() is simply a wrapper of the code to call the target function in the python file dynamically. The example given is the target "myfunc" in the python file "pathto/myfile.py". What do you mean by "using the function directly"?

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. In my example, I replaced: ``from mypath import Path`` with ``Path = callfunc("/folder/to/mypath.py", "Path")``. Thanks @Xiao-FengLi

Answer (score 2):

Just to import python file in another python file

lets say I have **helper.py** python file which has a display function like,

```
def display():
    print("I'm working sundar gsv")
```

Now in **app.py**, you can use the display function,

```
import helper
helper.display()
```

The output,

`I'm working sundar gsv`

**NOTE:** No need to specify the .py extension.

Answer (score 2):

One very unknown feature of Python is the ability to import `zip` files:

```
library.zip
|-library
|--__init__.py
```

The file `__init__.py` of the package contains the following:

```
def dummy():
    print 'Testing things out...'
```

We can write another script which can import a package from the zip archive. It is only necessary to add the zip file to the sys.path.

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'library.zip')

import library

def run():
    library.dummy()

run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this: `from filename import something`

example: `from client import Client`
Note that you do not need the `.py .pyw .pyui` extension.

Answer (score 1):

This may sound crazy but you can just create a symbolic link to the file you want to import if you're just creating a wrapper script to it.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways, as listed above, but I find that I **just want to import he contents of a file,** and don't want to have to write lines and lines and have to import *other* modules. So, I came up with a way to get the contents of a file, even with the dot syntax (`file.property`) as opposed to merging the imported file with yours.

First of all, here is my file which I'll import, `data.py`

```
    testString= "A string literal to import and test with"
```

**Note:** You could use the `.txt` extension instead.

In `mainfile.py`, start by opening and getting the contents.

```
    #!usr/bin/env python3
    Data=open('data.txt','r+').read()
```

Now you have the contents as a string, but trying to access `data.testString` will cause an error, as `data` is an instance of the `str` class, and even if it does have a property `testString` it will not do what you expected.
Next, create a class. For instance (pun intended), `ImportedFile`

```
    class ImportedFile:
```

And put this into it (with the appropriate indentation):

```
    exec(data)
```

And finally, re-assign `data` like so:

```
    data=ImportedFile()
```

And that's it! Just access like you would for any-other module, typing `print(data.testString)` will print to the console `A string literal to import and test with`.

If, however, you want the equivalent of `from mod import *` just drop the class, instance assignment, and de-dent the `exec`.

Hope this helps:)
-Benji

Comment: You seriously think reading the contents of the file as a string and then executing it is a good solution when we have all the other solutions people have posted?

Comment: @qwr Erm yes, I do. Many of the other answers don't work in some situations. Which is why I needed an easy way that was guaranteed to work. If you are incapable of seeing things from anothers point of view, you need to try using the official IDLE.

Answer (score 0):

```
from y import *
```

- Say you have a file x and y.
- You want to import y file to x.

then go to your x file and place the above command. To test this just put a print function in your y file and when your import was successful then in x file it should print it.