# Adding a directory to sys.path with pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

I'm trying to add a directory to PATH with code like this:

```
PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).parents[2]
sys.path.append(
    PROJECT_DIR / 'apps'
)
```

It doesn't work. If I do print `sys.path` I see something like this:

```
[..., PosixPath('/opt/project/apps')]
```

How should I fix this code? Is it normal to write `str(PROJECT_DIR / 'apps')`?

Comment: why would you want to avoid using `str`?

Comment: I don't want to avoid this. I just ask what the proper way to use pathlib.

Comment: re. you second question (since it's not covered in answers): yes, it's normal. Documentation mentions `str`: [The string representation of a path is the raw filesystem path itself (in native form, e.g. with backslashes under Windows), which you can pass to any function taking a file path as a string.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> A program is free to modify this list for its own purposes. **Only strings should be added to `sys.path`; all other data types are ignored during import.**

Add the path as a string to `sys.path`:

```
PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).parents[2]
sys.path.append(
    str(PROJECT_DIR / 'apps')
)
```

`PROJECT_DIR` is an instance of [`PosixPath`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PosixPath) which has all the goodies like `/` and `.parents` etc. You need to convert it to a `str`ing if you want to append it to `sys.path`.

Comment: You may want to `resolve()` the Path before adding it to sys.path.  That makes it absolute -- __file__ isnt't always absolute.

Comment: @florisla as this is done at runtime there is no need for that (as long as you do not move the modules before they are imported).

Answer (score 7):

Support for path-like-objects on `sys.path` is coming (see [this pull request](https://bugs.python.org/pull_request21106)) but not here yet.

Comment: It seems the [discussion is stuck](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/76823)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `os.fspath`. It return the file system representation of the path.

```
import os
    
PROJECT_DIR = Path(__file__).parents[2]
APPS_DIR = PROJECT_DIR / 'apps'
sys.path.append(os.fspath(APPS_DIR))
```

Documentation:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fspath

Comment: [May as well just use `str()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/b4d54a332ed593c9fcd0da25684c622a251d03ce/Lib/pathlib.py#L470-L471)

Answer (score -12):

```
project_dir = os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),"..","..")
sys.path.append(os.path.join(project_dir,"apps"))
#or maybe you need it at the start of the path
sys.path.insert(0,os.path.join(project_dir,"apps"))
```

why are you using this weird pathlib library instead of pythons perfectly good path utils?

Comment: may be a matter of taste - pathlib is pretty nice!

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: yeah its not using pathlib ... so it only answers the question if we assume (perhaps wrongly) that OP just really wants to extend the path... and pathlib was just something he thought he needed (or perhaps needs it for other reasons)

Comment: @hiroprotagonist yeah :) your answer is probably the right one (I upvoted it ... ) but figure ill leave this here just in case OP just wasnt familliar with builtin path tools ...

Comment: I guess you miss this part `.parents[2]` in your answer

Comment: So the answer on your question  is "pathlib/unipath/any_other_oo_path_lib helps me to avoid mistakes"

Comment: @Joran Beasley: by all means leave the answer! `os.path` is a perfectly fine library indeed! and for python <3 none of the `pathlib` stuff will work.

Comment: pathlib backported to python2.*

Comment: except it clearly lead to mistakes that you would not have had using the builtin ... and the mistakes were so hard you had to come ask SO for help :P but yes i see... i guess ... I still suggest builtins when they work for the task at hand @hiroprotagonist lol i read that as python love :P instead of python less than 3 :P

Comment: python love! (and: pathlib is builtin in python >3 and evidently backported to python 2.* [as mentioned by  kharandziuk]).

Comment: "this weird [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library" LOL.  This answer aged like fine milk.