# Problem with importing openCV on Jupiter notebook even though it is installed on my machine

Tags: python, opencv, pip, jupyter-notebook

So, I've been trying to import openCV to my python notebook but I'm having issues with it, I've tried multiple installation methods and I think I now have multiple versions for python 2.7 and 3.7.7 frankly, at this point I'm just lost.

Images(3): https://i.stack.imgur.com/7yuXD.jpg

Image 1 ->pip list showing opencv 
Image 2 -> pip list showing condo 
Image 3 -> importing error

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/. The issue is likely that you're running the program with a different Python installation than the one to which you added the libraries.

Comment: Pretty sure you have installed those packages in an another environment or for a different version of python

Comment: That's what I though too but I'm just a beginner at terminal and I have no idea how to change that, I tried a solution on here and one on GeeksforGeeks but still lost.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are using `python3.7.7` in jupyter. when you use `pip` to install opencv, it is probably installing it for the `python2.7`, so to installl it for `python3.7.7` you have to install it like this:

```
python3.7.7 -m pip install opencv-python
```

Comment: when I type that, this is what I get; `-bash: python3.7.7: command not found`

Comment: well replace python3.7.7 with the version of python you are using in jupyter.

Comment: you can type "python" and press TAB(2 times), it will suggest you with the versions installed.

Comment: so it ran for python3.7 here; https://pastebin.com/NXGz45En and when I run python_version() in Jupyter, version is 3.7.4 and I'm still unable to import

Comment: so now check it in jupyter

Comment: still the same :(

Comment: `Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.2.0.34)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.14.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from opencv-python) (1.18.4)` This is what I get when I try to run pip from notebook using sys library. still doesn't work

Comment: then check for this. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38110537/10049589