# Jupyter Notebook ImportError: No module named 'sklearn'

Tags: scikit-learn, jupyter, conda

I am trying to run on my local machine.  I get an error 
ImportError: No module named 'sklearn' only in jupyter notebook
It works fine when I use python from the command line both with the carnd-term1 env activated and deactivated.

I have installed sklearn with pip, apt-get and conda.  Also tried conda upgrade scikit-learn.  Both with the env active and deactivated.

---

```
(carnd-term1) matt@Malta:~/sdc$ conda upgrade scikit-learn
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .
# All requested packages already installed.
# packages in environment at /home/matt/anaconda3/envs/carnd-term1:
#
scikit-learn 0.18.1 np112py35_1
```

---

```
(carnd-term1) matt@Malta:~/sdc$ python3
Python 3.5.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan 19 2017, 15:28:33) 
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sklearn
>>>
```

---

```
   ...: (carnd-term1) matt@Malta:~/sdc$ ipython
   ...: Python 3.5.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan 19 2017, 15:28:33) 
   ...: Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   ...: 
   ...: IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
   ...: ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
   ...: %quickref -> Quick reference.
   ...: help      -> Python's own help system.
   ...: object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
   ...: 
   ...: In [1]: import sklearn
   ...: 
   ...: In [2]: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
   ...: 
   ...: In [3]: (carnd-term1) matt@Malta:~/sdc$ ipython
   ...:    ...: Python 3.5.2 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Jan 19 2017, 15:28:33) 
   ...:    ...: Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
   ...:    ...: 
   ...:    ...: IPython 5.1.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
   ...:    ...: ?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
   ...:    ...: %quickref -> Quick reference.
   ...:    ...: help      -> Python's own help system.
   ...:    ...: object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.
   ...:    ...: 
   ...:    ...: In [1]: import sklearn
   ...:    ...: 
   ...:    ...: In [2]: from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
   ...:    ...: 
   ...:    ...: In [3]:
```

---

Doesn't work from jupyter notebook.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install jupyter notebook into this environment?

Answer (score 7):

This generally means that the two are not the same environment. The best thing to check is `sys.executable` and make sure that it is what you expect. If it's the notebook that's not using the `sys.executable` you expect, the first step may be to check your PATHs:

```
which jupyter
which jupyter-notebook
```

The most likely issue is that the notebook stack isn't in your conda env, which you can solve with:

```
conda install notebook
```

The second most likely is that you have installed a kernelspec (e.g. with `ipython kernel install --user`) that's overriding your env. You can see where your kernels are with:

```
jupyter kernelspec list
```

To make sure you have the IPython kernel installed in the same env, you can do:

```
conda install ipykernel
ipython kernelspec install --sys-prefix
```

and check `jupyter kernelspec list` again after.

Comment: I tried following your instruction and it didn't work eventhough all conditions where met. Then i realized that i was in the python3 virtual environment of my conda installation. So i exited that notebook. Checked the default python version (without the virtualenv) , it was python 2.7 . Fired up the REPL, followed by the jupyter notebook. BOOM was able to from sklearn.  Leaving the comment here incase it helps someone

Comment: I think I have the kernel issue but I'm not using conda, just plain old pip. What is the fix for that?

Answer (score 5):

Let's learn a general approach to solve these sort of problems. The solution is quite straightforward. Basically has three steps:

1. Finding where the pip package is installed.
2. Adding that directory to path.
3. Finally, importing the package.

**Finding where the pip package is installed:**

```
!pip show PACKAGE_NAME
```

Don't forget this `!` before the command if you are executing it in `jupyter-notebook`. This will give you the path to that package (with possibly with other information). Get the path given inside `Location`.

**Adding that directory to path:** This following code should go before you import that package in `jupyter`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/the/package')
```

**Now import the package:**

```
import PACKAGE_NAME
```

**So, for `sklearn`:**

Get the sklearn directory:

```
!pip show scikit-learn
```

Add directory:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/sklearn')
```

*For example, if you are using `anaconda` than the `site-packages` folder will contain all `conda` installed packages for **that** environment. **Inside this path** there is the **folder** `sklearn` which we are trying to import*:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/home/hafiz031/anaconda3/envs/NLP/lib/python3.8/site-packages')
```

Now import the desired package as usual:

```
import sklearn
```

**References:**

1. [which version and where scikit-learn is installed](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html)
2. [Python: Best way to add to sys.path relative to the current running script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42446686/6907424)

Answer (score 2):

If you use virtual environment, then you need to install Notebook into your environment:

```
pip install notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating the package may solve your issue

```
conda upgrade scikit-learn
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried almost everything and this finally worked:

Change your Jupiter notebook kernel from `python3.xx.x` (anything other than `Ipykernel`) to `Ipykernel`.

Answer (score -1):

You can install library on which enviromment you use

```
pip install sklearn

conda install sklearn
```