# sys.path.append and difference at "from somefolder import module" vs "import smth"

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

May someone explain why when I when I use sys.path.append I cannot access to my module via structure "from somefolder import module"?

```
import sys

sys.path.append('../models/research/object_detection/utils')


import dataset_util
```

> cannot import name 'dataset_util'

whilst - `from utils import dataset_util` works fine

Is there any decent explanation of this behavior? And what should I do with **sys.path.append** to have ability to use the structure "from somefolder import module"?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe you need to use absolute paths for `sys.path`s.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Best way to add to sys.path relative to the current running script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663076/python-best-way-to-add-to-sys-path-relative-to-the-current-running-script)