# How to use a Python function defined in a separate file in a Python chunk in Rmarkdown?

Tags: python, r-markdown

So, I have a file called 'function.py' which includes the simple function:

```
def square(x):
  return x*x
```

I have a second bit of code like this:

```
from test import square
print(square(2))
```

If I store the second bit of code in a python file and run it in the terminal it works and gives the expected answer.

However, if I add a Python chunk in a Rmarkdown document like this:

````
```{python}
from test import square
print(square(2))
```
````

I get the error:

> "Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/var/folders/g7/462tmml173nfzj0j8437t9_m0000gn/T/RtmptMA22N/chunk-code-48764cec023f.txt", line 1, in 
>       from test import square
>   ImportError: cannot import name square"

The Rmarkdown file and the python file are in the same directory. Answers about the specific error message are about dependencies, but I don't see how that's relevant in my case?

I've searched the web and read documentation, but I think I am missing something important. Thank you for the help!

**Edit:**
Solved by specifically changing the path to the current working directory.

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
import test
print(test.square(2))
```

Comment: Have you read and tried the solutions detailed in [this GitHub issue thread?](https://github.com/rstudio/reticulate/issues/108)

Comment: Is test a folder ?

Comment: 1) The GitHub issue thread: yes, I have read this. The reticulate function that is given as solution is meant to be used in a R chunk, whereas I want to import within a Python chunk. The other solution of using "sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__)))" is not quite clear to me; not sure how to implement it.
2) test is not a folder, test.py is a file with the function

Comment: You can try to put your test.py in a folder and then import like this : 
from yourfolder.test import *

Comment: This solution does not work unfortunately. Am I missing something about what a module is exactly? Or am I missing something about how to define the location of the directory/file/function?

Comment: Solved! I have used sys.path.append(os.getcwd())

Answer (score 0):

Solved by specifically changing the path to the current working directory.

```
import sys, os
sys.path.append(os.getcwd())
import test
print(test.square(2))
```

Answer was based on [Python: Best way to add to sys.path relative to the current running script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663076/python-best-way-to-add-to-sys-path-relative-to-the-current-running-script/8663119#8663119).