# Getting Module Import error with unit testing in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, python-unittest

Hello Python Programmers

I'm getting a weird module import error during unittest. Not able to find the root cause.
Here is how my directory structure looks like

```
Main_folder
   |
   |
   Module_x
       |  ABC.py
   |
   |
   Module_y
        | DEF.py
   |
   |
   test
       | unit_tests
             | test_ABC.py
```

In test_ABC.py I'm importing the following

```
from Module_x import ABC
```

I get the error as "No module name Module_x"

I've created `__init__.py` file at each folder

I don't get any error if I use the same line from DEF.py

Please help if you're aware about why I am getting this issue?

I am using Python 3.5 Anaconda Distribution

Thanks

Comment: What is the working directory?  `print(os.getcwd())`

Comment: The `cwd` is main_folder

Comment: Try running the test from `Main_folder` like `python test/unit_tests/test_ABC.py`

Comment: @JRajan Did tried.. but same results

Comment: Then you need to add the working directory in the Python path, so that Python knows there are other modules that need to loaded. You can use the linked answer as a pointer to adding directories dynamically https://stackoverflow.com/a/8663119/690576 or use the below answer for adding it to global python path.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a weird problem but a common one.

You can add your root into `PYTHONPATH` to solve this problem: `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/project_root python test_ABC.py` or something else similar.

Comment: Hi Sraw, I call it weird because I can access the same from DEF.py without coming to any path related issue? Any idea ?

Comment: The problem is how you run that `DEF.py`, I believe you run it under `Main_folder` while not run that test cases under `Main_folder`. It should be impossible that you can get `Main_folder` as `os.getcwd()` in your case. Or you should be able to find that module.

Comment: Yes you're right... The DEF.py called from a file in main_folder.  If my tests are called from a file placed in main_folder it works