# How can I fix these relative import error

Tags: python, python-3.6, python-import

I have a folder structure like this, each time I attempt to use relative import, error raises

```
├── graphics
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── A
│   │   ├── __init__.py
│   │   ├── grok.py
│   │   └── spam.py
    └── B
        ├── __init__.py
        └── bar.py


spam.py/
    def func():
        pass
bar.py/
    def f():
        pass
```

All these codes are tested in grok.py:

```
from . import spam
# ImportError: cannot import name 'spam'

from .spam import func
# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.spam'; '__main__'     
is not a package

from ..B import bar
# ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

None of the codes below cause any error:

```
from graphics.A import spam
from graphics.A.spam import func
from graphics.B import bar
from graphics.B.bar import f
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume that when you say "*tested in grok.py*" that you are running it like these:

```
python3 graphics/A/grok.py
python3 A/grok.py
python3 grok.py
```

From the Python documentation on [Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) and [Intra-Package References](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references), there is a note there that says:

> Note that relative imports are based on the name of the current
>   module. Since the name of the main module is always "`__main__`",
>   **modules intended for use as the main module of a Python application**
>   **must always use absolute imports**.

When you run `grok.py`, it gets treated as the main module, and imports will only work if you used absolute imports (assuming you made no changes to `sys.path`, we'll get to that later). You can test that by putting `print(__name__)` at the start of grok.py, which will print out "`__main__`".

Your relative imports are *actually* going to work if you had a separate python file (ex. `main.py`) under the graphics package that calls your `grok` module:

```
├── graphics
│   ├── __init__.py
|   ├── main.py     <<---- add this
│   ├── A
│   ├── B
```

In `main.py`, let's just import the `grok` module:

```
from A import grok
```

In `grok.py`, let's test the relative imports:

```
from . import spam
spam.spam_func()

from .spam import spam_func
spam_func()

from B import bar
bar.bar_func()
```

In `spam.py`:

```
def spam_func():
    print("spammy")
```

In `bar.py`:

```
def bar_func():
    print("barry")
```

When you run `main.py`:

```
graphics$ python3 main.py
spammy
spammy
barry
```

You won't get any of the previous errors. The relative imports work. Notice that to import from `B`, I used `from B` instead of `from ..B`. This is because the import paths are from the point of view of `main.py`. You can test this by adding this at the top of `main.py`:

```
import sys
print(sys.path)
# prints a list, ['/path/to/graphics/',...]
```

If you did `from ..B` that means `/path/to/graphics/../` which of course does not have the `B` module (hence, you'll get the "*attempted relative import beyond top-level package*" error)

---

Now let's say you don't want to use a separate `main.py` and you want to run `grok.py` directly. What you can do is manually add the path to the `graphics` package to `sys.path`. Then you can do `from A` and `from B` in `grok.py`.

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/full/path/to/graphics/")

from A import spam
spam.spam_func()

from B import bar
bar.bar_func()
```

If you want to go about "hacking" the `sys.path`, I suggest reading more on [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path) and checking other related posts that discuss [ways of adding paths to `sys.path`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8663076/2745495).