# How can I fix module not found in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have my target.py file in `Starterpack/ModulesAndPackages/target.py`
and I have my script file in `Starterpack/Scripts/Bad.py`

My `ModulesAndPackages` folder has the `__init__.py` file but I still get this error `No module named ModulesAndPackages` when I type `from ModulesAndPackages.target import Target` in the script file.

I've tried the `sys.path.append()` and `sys.path.insert()` but none worked. In my editor there is no error but when I run it, it gives the error.

script file:

```
mandp_dir = "./ModulesAndPackages"
scripts_dir = "./Scripts"
main_dir = ".."

os.chdir(Path(main_dir))
from ModulesAndPackages.target import Target
```

target.py file:

```
import time
import os
import keyboard

class Target():
    def __init__(self, ip, port, packetsize, time=None):
        self.ip = ip
        self.port = port
        self.packetsize = packetsize
        self.time = time

    def attack(self):
        pass
```

I expected it to work if I added the `__init__.py` file, but it doesn't.

Comment: `ModulesAndPackages` is located in the same directory as your script?

Comment: @xbound My script is in Starter Pack/Scripts and target.py is in Starter Pack/ModulesAndPackages

Comment: Does your `ModulesAndPackages` package has `__init__.py` file inside?

Comment: @xbound Yes it does.

Comment: You're launching your script inside Scripts directory?

Comment: @xbound I'm not sure. Any way to check?

Comment: You could add path to your manually to `sys.path` but I would personally discourage this and instead make starter_pack as python package and then import  from starter_pack.ModulesAndPackages.target import Target

Comment: @xbound But Starter_Pack is where i hold everything not only that 2 folders.

Comment: Try `sys.path.append("..")` instead of `os.chdir(Path(main_dir))`

Comment: Generally try to make all scripts at the same level as your packages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to add the dir to the path python searches, not change your current directory, e.g.:

```
scripts_dir = "./Scripts"
main_dir = ".."

sys.path.append(Path(main_dir))
```

Also, check this out: [python-best-way-to-add-to-sys-path-relative-to-the-current-running-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663076/python-best-way-to-add-to-sys-path-relative-to-the-current-running-script)

Answer (score 0):

Add the `__init__.py` file to your StarterPack folder too and use the `from StarterPack.ModulesAndPackages.target import yourFunctionName`

Comment: Starterpack is the main folder where i hold more than the 2 folders

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding additional path to `sys.path`:

```py
import os, sys
from pathlib import Path
main_dir = ".."

sys.path.append("..")
from ModulesAndPackages.target import Target
```

if you're doing this just for some small testing then it's ok.

**BUT**: I would discourage doing this in most projects as this is generally not very good approach. Instead your script should be at the same level as `ModulesAndPackages` like this in order for `from ModulesAndPackages.target import Target` to import properly:

```
├── ModulesAndPackages
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── target.py
└── script.py
```

Here `script.py` will act as sort of `main` starting point.