# sys.path and PYTHONPATH but not importing local library from another folder

Tags: python, import, python-import

I can't for the life of me figure out what's wrong here. I'm trying to import a local library that's in an upstream path:

```
root/
    folder1/
        test1.py
    folder2/
        test2.py
```

In this scenario I want to import `folder1` in `test2.py`.

In `test2.py`, I use `sys.path.append` to add the file path to `folder1`:

```
import os
import sys
fileDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
parentDir = os.path.dirname(fileDir)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(parentDir, 'folder1'))

print(sys.path)
import folder1.test1
```

But when I'm in root and run `python3 folder2/test2.py`, I still get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder1'`.

I've also tried hardcoding `$PYTHONPATH` and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Path stores where to look for modules. Right now your code seeks `folder1` module **in** folder1 directory! Just do `import test1`, because that's what **in** folder1. Or add parentDir (without specifying) folder1 to path.

Comment: Similar question as this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61322726/how-to-import-modules-from-a-file-in-a-deeper-directory/61326547#61326547
You should remove the `join`. Then you can do `import folder1.testx`. With the the `join` it would just be `import testx`

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help!!