# Relative imports for the trillionth time

Tags: python, import, python-import, relative-path, relative-import

I have the following data structure:

```
project/
    folder_a/
        file.py
    folder_b/
        useful_functions.py
```

I am running my `file.py` and attempting to import a set of functions I have written within `useful_functions.py`.

At first I tried the following:

```
from ..folder_b.useful_functions import function_a
```

But got the following error:

```
ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package
```

I then removed the two dots at the beginning of the import statement which initially worked. I have since revisited this project with no changes and I am faced with a new error message. The following code:

```
from folder_b.useful_functions import function_a
```

Gives me the following error message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'folder_b'
```

I find it very strange that one time it works and later with no changes the import fails. I really would like to solve this with relative imports as I would like the code to work other machines with different absolute file paths.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From which path are you running the file?

Comment: How are you running this file?

Comment: I am running the file from within spyder 4. I have found a workaround with the following post by appending the cwd (in this case folder a) to the sys path. I'm surprised this is necessary, I'm sure there must be a simpler way. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663076/python-best-way-to-add-to-sys-path-relative-to-the-current-running-script)

Answer (score 0):

Well for the trillionth time running a script directly inside a package is considered an antipattern. I do not know how spyder runs stuff but presumably does

```
python file.py # from inside folder_a
```

This should be changed to

```
python -m folder_a.file # from inside project
```

This would resolve relative imports among packages inside project folder alright and will not need any sys.path or PYTHONPATH hacks