# importing from directory which imports from another file and loads a file [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, path, pathlib

My dummy project tree is as below:

```
base|
    |test.py
    |model
         |code1.py
         |code2.py
         |hi.npy
```

`hi.npy` is a simpe string stored / any file that I need to load in code1.

`code2.py`

```
import numpy as np 

def pr(a):
    print(f'hi {a}')
```

`code1.py`

```
from code2 import pr # I load the function from code2
import numpy as np 
a = np.load('hi.npy') # I try to load the file
```

When I'm inside model, I can run both `code1` and `code2` without any issue.

But when I go one level up, to the base folder.

`test.py`

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path

sys.path.append(Path(__file__).parent / "model")

print(sys.path)

from model.code1 import *
```

Even though I'm adding the model path to the system as suggested by many similar answers ([Python: Best way to add to sys.path relative to the current running script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663076/python-best-way-to-add-to-sys-path-relative-to-the-current-running-script)), neither the `pr` function nor the `a` file is loaded successfully from `test.py`.

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'code2'`

`FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hi.npy'`

I can change the design of the file structure/move the files/use OOP to fix the issue but is there anything much simple method that enables me to load both `a` and `pr` from `test.py`

**1. without manually changing file paths/imports inside code1, code2** and

**2. be able to run test.py (from base) and code1.py (from model) simultaneously.**

Comment: is `base` your project parent directory ?

Comment: yes, model is another directory inside base.

Comment: what is your execution path or running script ?

Comment: I get error when I run `python test.py` inside the base directory.

Comment: in code1.py and code2.py import module as `from model.code2 imprt xyz` it will solve your problem

Comment: thanks, that definitely helps. But for that, I also have to change every file path reference in code1 and code2 with 'model/path', that will break things if I run code1, code2 inside model. Is there a way I can keep running both without changing the file paths, imports manually.