# Python not recognising another file

Tags: python

I am creating a python module. To test it i put the file in the same directory and then wrote the code

```
import mymodule
mymodule.dofunction
```

python then said `>>>no module named mymodule` but they are in the same directory.

Comment: [CHECK THIS LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: What file name did you use for your module? `mymodule.py` or just `mymodule`. The former is correct, the latter not.

Comment: did you try: from FILENAME import YOU'REMODULE

Comment: Is your module in the python path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting from previous answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279237/import-a-module-from-a-relative-path). Explicitly state that you want to use the current directory.

Also, consider that you need an "__init__.py" file in each directory you are importing from.

```
import os, sys
lib_path = os.path.abspath('.')
sys.path.append(lib_path)

import mymodule
```

More information on the import system [here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html).

Comment: You can put any directory you want there. '.' is the current directory.

Comment: Also, I can't stress enough that you should learn the import system better.