# How can I import the function?

Tags: python

I have a Python function in a file called `func.py`

```
def calc(x,y):
    return x*y
```

I have to import this function while working in another file called mytask.py

How can I import the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the file in the same directory and then have a statement

```
from func import calc
```

To import from a different directory

1. Add the file to a new directory, call it funcs
2. Create a file `__init__.py` and have a line `__all__ = ['calc']`
3. Import as `from funcs import func`

Reference

- http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html
- [Python: How to import other Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files)
- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Is not it possible to import from the different dir?

Comment: It is possible. You have to specify the directory

Comment: Rather than doing this, is not it possible to specify the dir and import from that dir?

Comment: @musk ou will have to add it to sys.path or change the environmental variables. This is simpler technique. Refer the links. You will get better answer.

Comment: Can I add a dir into sys.path from coding in python, how?