# Import variable from parent directory in python package

Tags: python, import

I'm a bit new to python and I'm trying to learn Flask.

My project structure looks like this:

```
project/
   __init__.py
   views/
       __init__.py
       profile.py
```

My `project/__init__.py` looks like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from views.profile import app
app = Flask(__name__)
```

I'm trying to import `app` from `project/__init__.py` into`profile.py`.

I've tried some ways that none of them worked.

Comment: What have you tried and why did it not work for you? Which kind of error do you get?

Answer (score 2):

Finally I found an answer which works:

In my profile.py I put this:

```
import sys, os.path
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath('../'))
from ccs import app
```

Comment: [please try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786300/maya-how-to-create-python-scripts-with-more-than-one-file/32794372#32794372)