# Relative Path Python Error

Tags: python, import, path, directory, sys

My python file is in the folder *'RealData/Python/run.py'*
What I need to do in **run.py** is to import another python file: **plot_ensembles.py** which is in the folder *'RealData/convolution/plot_ensembles.py'*

My code returns an error:

```
import sys
sys.path.append( 'myname/Documents/RealData/convolution')
import plot_ensembles
```

> ImportError: No module named 'plot_ensembles'

Probably this is a stupid mistake...

Comment: What system are you running on?

Comment: What if you do `import ../../convolution/plot_ensemble` ?

Comment: @Drjnker If I run ´import ../../convolution/plot_ensembles´ it returns invalid syntax

Comment: See Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try In the file that has the script, you want to do something like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.realpath('../convolution'))
import plot_ensembles
```

Comment: and then `import filename` ?
This returns the error "No module named filename"