# Python: how to properly import a function from another file that depends on module

Tags: python

Suppose I have two files. The first one contains all the functions I've written and which I usually import from my main file:

```
# my_functions.py

def sqrt_product(a, b):
    from math import sqrt
    return sqrt(a*b)

def create_df(lst):
    from pandas import DataFrame as df
    return df(lst)
```

and my main file:

```
# main.py
from my_functions import sqrt_product, create_df

print(sqrt_product(3, 3))
print(create_df([1, 2, 3])
```

Is there a more efficient way to import this function? Do I have to import every module for every function I create? WHat if I have several functions in the same file that relies on the same module?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files) seems highly relevant.

Comment: What's the objection here? What's inefficient about importing this way? What do you mean by "do I have to import every module for every function I create"?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist my specific concern is with the import... inside every function. Is it the best way to import every module inside the function (in my_functions.py)?

Comment: @mat  Importing individually is the "best" to import functions/class methods because it keep the namespace clean and is memory efficient.

Comment: @mat I don't ever import inside functions, as a rule. I'm not following why you think that's necessary. Your example certainly doesn't demonstrate it.

Comment: @mat Oh I think I get it now. You can move that `pandas` import to the top of the file and that function will still work no matter where you import it, with no additional imports from `pandas` necessary.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist that was the answer I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how.

```
 import my_functions as repo
```

Usage:

```
repo.sqrt_product(a, b)
repo.create_df(lst)

print(repo.sqrt_product(3, 3))
print(repo.create_df([1, 2, 3])
```

"repo" is now in the namespace. Just like `import pandas as pd`,  `pd` is in namespace.

```
# my_functions.py
from math   import sqrt
from pandas import DataFrame as df
#Or import pandas as pd 

def sqrt_product(a, b):
    return sqrt(a*b)

def create_df(lst):
    return df(lst)
    #return pd.DataFrame(lst)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `from pandas import DataFrame` (optionally with `as df`) to the top of `my_functions.py` and redefine `create_df` just to be:

```
def create_df(lst):
    return DataFrame(lst)   # or df(lst) if you used as
```

The `create_df` function will still work when you import it without requiring you to import anything from `pandas`. It will be imported with everything it needs to do its thing.

This isn't just true for imported dependencies.

```
x = 5
def y():
    return x
```

If you go somewhere else and `import y`, you will find that `y()` returns 5, whether or not you imported `x`. Whatever the function object needs to do its job, it carries with it. This includes when it is imported into another module.

Comment: Just by the way, I'm assuming this is a toy example, but if all `create_df` does is pass an argument to `DataFrame`, I'd reconsider having it in the first place and just call `DataFrame`.

Answer (score 0):

U can do this as well.

```
# main.py
from my_functions import *

print(sqrt_product(3, 3))
print(create_df([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: Wildcards as bad they may cause  conflicts in namespace.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this.

1. Import the file from the current directory.

   - make sure the file you are importing from doesn't have any spaces or dashes in its file name. (Ex: **thing_to_import_from.py**, not **thing to import from.py**.)
   - make sure both files are in the same directory.

     Import the file and function  like so:

     ```
     from thing_to_import_from import function_to_import1, function_to_import2
     ```
2. Import the file from another directory.

   - If the file is in a folder or subfolder within the same directory, and the path contains no spaces, it can be imported like so:

     ```
     from folder/subfolder/thing_folder/thing_to_import_from import function_to_import
     ```
   - else, add the path to the python sys.path, then import as before.

     ```
     import sys
     sys.path.insert(0, "/folder/subfolder/thing folder")
     from thing_to_import_from import function_to_import
     ```
3. Make the file into a python module.

   - You should ONLY do this if you intend to use the file with multiple programs for an extended period of time. Don't junk up your Lib folder!

     1. Make a folder in your Lib folder with the desired library name. (The default location of Lib for Python2.7 on Windows is **C:\Python27\Lib**, for example.)
     2. Place your script with the functions to import within this folder.
     3. Create an **__init__.py** script within this folder. If your script doesn't need any special initialization and doesn't import any other non-library scripts, this can be a blank file.
     4. Import your script as a module!

        ```
        from thing_to_import_from import function_to_import
        ```