# python not importing from current directory

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

I'm using python 2.7 in a linux environment and I'm having trouble importing a .py file under certain conditions.  My directory-tree is as follows:

```
/mainFolder
    executable.py
    /Folder
         input_file.py
```

`executable.py` imports `input_file.py` with the line `__import__('input_file')`

When I am in the folder `mainFolder/Folder` and I run `../executable.py` I get the output: `ImportError: No module named input_file`

And when I move `input_file.py` into `mainFolder` it works.  From looking at it I'm under the impression that `input_file.py` isn't in python's path and I know how to fix that.

I'm under the impression though that it should work as is, as this is code that is from a github repository and presumably works on the author's computer, but this is apparently not the case.

Is there a setting I can change so I don't have to do something like `sys.path.append(0,'mainFolder/Folder')`?

Comment: Why are you using the import function `__import__()` instead of the plain `import` keyword?

Comment: I'm using the `__import__()` because I'm actually passing `executable.py` the input file as an input which it imports that way, I don't want to have to alter `executable.py` every time I use a new input file.

Answer (score 3):

"Packages" in python are identified by a file called

> **__init__.py**

in the root of this package folder.

In this case, your tree should appears like:

```
/mainFolder
    executable.py
    /Folder
         **__init__.py**
         input_file.py
```

In this case, if you want import module: input_file as a module, you can declare in executable:

```
from Folder import input_file
```

or even

```
from Folder.input_file import *
from Folder import *
```

As alternative and following explanation found in [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349998/176765), I implemented an example for your directory structure:

`executable.py` file content:

```
Folder = __import__('Folder.input_file')
print(Folder.input_file.summm(1,2))
```

`input_file.py` file content:

```
def summm(a, b):
    return a+b
```

It is ugly, but was the to build an example following your original structure. In this case, it is not ncessary to add `__init__.py` file inside `Folder` folder.

Comment: I've thought about this too, but there aren't any __init__.py files in the github repository, and shouldn't python recognize packages that are in the directory you are in on your operating system?

Comment: James, I edited the post for the structure you described. It works in your case?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily fix it

```
import Folder.input_file
```

or

```
__import__('Folder.input_file')
```

Where `Folder` is the name of the folder `input_file.py` is in.

Comment: Is this a quirk of Python 2.7, since it works flawless with Python 3.5.2

Comment: You might need an `__init__.py` in `Folder` for that to work. It can be empty.

Comment: At least with 3.5.2 you don't.
Andrea said the same thing