# Python import class from other file, and use function from that class from the imported file

Tags: python-3.x

Im creating a framework in python, and I have two files main_part.py and class_part.py, in class_part.py I have a class CreateParserClass and inside the class CreateParserClass I have a function create_parser that will create a parser, how can I import the class CreateParserClass from the python file class_part.py, and use it to execute the function create_parser from the class CreateParserClass in main_part.py?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to import other Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: `import class_part`?