# Python 2.7 Running External .py Files in Program

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a .py file and I want to make it so I can type it's name in another .py file and have it run all the code from the first file.

Remember, this is in Python 2.7 on a Raspberry Pi 3.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you not just put it in the same directory and import it or do you need it to run externally?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to import other Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven They are both on my Pi's desktop.

Comment: I guess I'm asking if you need second.py to run as a separate process or if it can run as part of the process that is calling it.

Comment: @ThisGuyCantEven I'm doing it like this so I can run a bunch of programs with on .py file and have it neater and easier to read.

Comment: Then I do believe you should import them and run them from a driver class. I would check out what @KSigWyatt posted about the duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can use execfile() or os.system() to solve your problem. But I think, the correct way to tackle your problem is to import the file in your current script and call the imported file's functions or main function directly from your script.

Comment: What would the sytnax for that look like?

Comment: First have both of your files in same working directly. Then simply write "import filename" at the top of your script. Then you can simply call filename.function() to call that function.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `os.system("second.py")` or using `subprocess.Popen` from you first script should work for you.

Comment: I just got a blank ">>> " from the IDLE Shell.