# Python import class from other files

Tags: python

I have three files under the same directory, namely, main.py, Newtester.py, and fileUtility.py. In Newtester.py there is a class named Function. In main.py, there are the following codes:

```
from file.py import *
...
def main():
    ...
    funcs = parseFuncSpec(funcInputFile)
```

parseFuncSpec is defined in fileUtilities.py as:

```
some code to import Newtester.py
def parseFuncSpec(fName):
    curFunc = function(funcName, numTest, [], score)
```

Regardless of what I put in import Newtester.py, I always get an error saying "Function" (the class defined in the file "Newtester.py") is not defined. Following [Python: How to import other Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files), I have attempted

```
import Newtester
__import__("Newtester")
exec("Newtester.py")
exec("Newtester")
import importlib
importlib.__import__("Newtester")
os.system("Newtester.py")
```

But none of them seemed to work. Any advice is appreciated. See https://github.com/r2dong/unitTesting if you are interested in seeing the complete files.

Comment: @Gahan what are you talking about? That's not deprecated. That is the correct way to define a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are not using it correctly

well when you use import statement like below only Newstester file is imported

```
import Newtester
```

hence instead of using `parseFuncSpec()` directly you have to use it as `Newtester.parseFuncSpec()`

or to use `parseFuncSpec()` directly you need to use below import statement:

```
from Newtester import parseFuncSpec
```