# How to import in py

Tags: python, python-3.x

hey I have this file in py, it is called `Numbers.py`:

```
Numbers=[1,3,5,7]
for i in Numbers:
    if i%2==0:
        print(i)
    else: 
        i%2==1
    print(i)
for l in Numbers:
        if l>1 & i%l==1:
            print(l)
```

how can I import it in another one?

Comment: `import Numbers`

Comment: Check out the Python documentation on modules: https://docs.python.org/release/3.6.4/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to import other Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files)

Answer (score 0):

If your project is rather simple, you need to make a new file called `__init__.py` to tell python your marking the current directory where `Numbers.py` is a package that can be imported.

Next in your other `py` file you can do:

```
import .Numbers #if you want to import everything
from .Numbers import * # if you want to import all the variables and functions in same namespace
```