# Function calls to multiple different files in python

Tags: python, function, python-import

I would like to create multiple files with my own functions and store it as multiple script files. what is the best way to make it work.
How do I call it from another python script?

For example I have the files `a.py`, `b.py`, `c.py` and `x.py` in the files `a.py`, `b.py` and `c.py`. I would like to use functions from the other imported files.

```
def a():
  print("Function a is called")
  print(c())
  return 1
```

b.py

```
def b():
  # Something
  print("function b is called.")
  return 2
```

c.py

```
def c():
  # de Something
  print("Function C is called.")
  print(b())
  return 3

print(a())
```

---

x.py

```
from a import *
from b import *
from c import *
print(a())
print(b())
print(c())
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's the goal with this? If they are in the same directory you could use `os.sys()` to call them? Or do you have a different use case?

Comment: what is the problem with the code you posted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: How to import other Python files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: The case i have is that i have a script with functions with ask questions though the serial port.  TransmitCom(Com,"help")
  time.sleep(0.20)
  Error = 0
  ReceiveCom(Com,"help", 200 ,"IGNORE")

Comment: You have `a` calling `c` and `c` calling `b`. If you want to do that then `a` needs to import `c` and `c` needs to import `b`. But if you then want `b` to import `a` you will have circular references and it won't work. Putting one function or class per file is common in compiled languages but it doesn't work well in dynamic ones.

Comment: The case i have is that i have a script with functions with ask questions though the serial port. The interface of te total program is in main.py. I use wx python for that.
So for the separate test functions witch are called from mail.py I have imported test_functions.py i the file test_functions.py i would like to cal functions from serial_functions.py


from Serial_functions import *
from test_functions import *

if test1:
 print("Test succeed.")
else:
 print("Test failed.")

if test2:
 print("Test succeed.")
else:
 print("Test failed.")

Comment: @JarredParr The idea is to make a saparation between main program the test functions and the serial communication functions the scripts are all in the same directory.  The main.py is ment for the gui the serial_functions.py is ment for the serial communication and i would like the test_functions.py as simple as possible.

Comment: @LeoRuyven I understand your wish to compartmentalize the code, but if you want a function `a` in `a.py` to call function `c` in `c.py` then `a` needs to import `c`. Doing all the imports in `x` has no effect on `a`. `import` is not a `#include`, it is an executable statement, which is why circular imports don't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine.
Function c() should return some value (integer) like other functions, a, b.
Within x.py, just import should do, e.g.

x.py

```
import a
import b
import c
print(a())
print(b())
print(c())
```

make sure all indentations are ok

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that if i run x.py I have an error in module c.py. NameError: name 'a' is not defined