# Python 3 use a code from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I have two Python files. In my main file I work with a openpyxl module. In my second file I have many string lines with concatenating using Excel file cells, for example:

```
'/ip address=' + sheet['D'+ row].value + '\n'
```

and many others. But there is a problem, if I import that file to a main file using:

```
from file2 import *
```

I get many errors about undefined names like:

> NameError: name 'sheet' is not defined

And it is really defined only in my main file, like:

```
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename='clients.xlsx')
sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name('Page1')
```

How can I import everything from my file2 and get it work?

Comment: why not import openpyxl  into file 2?

Comment: Well, I should then define many other large string variables in my file2, cause it also has many refers to them. And it adds too many lines to a file2 + i want to have some more files in future

Comment: well but otherwise it doesn't compile properly. I think python doesn't just add the files into one big file and then compile. It is compiling on the fly and your imported file is not compiling properly

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can wrap my head around it, `import` only imports functions. `execfile(*path*)` should work for you in your case.
There are some more ways to [import python into python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/python-how-to-import-other-python-files#20749411), which you might want to check out.

Comment: No, `import` imports everything. But everything must be qualified with the name of the module: if you `import file`, then you access stuff at the top level of `file.py` as `file.wb` or `file.sheet`.