# Importing local modules in python v. IPython

Tags: python, import, python-import

I've found that IPython and python handle the loading of local modules differently and I wonder if someone could explain why this happens.

Suppose that my project is structured as:

```
top_level/
  src/
    a.py
    b.py
    __init__.py
```

The contents of `b.py` are:

```
from src.a import foo
foo()
```

and then `a.py` has a function `foo`:

```
def foo():
  print('It worked!')
```

File `__init__.py` is blank.

If I call ipython and python from `top_level` I get two different result:

[image: IPython works, python does not.]

Why does one work and not the other? Is it possible to make python handle similar to IPython or is there a more pythonic way to handle cases like this?

Version Info:

- Python: 3.6.3
- IPython: 6.1.0 (with 3.6.3 Python)

---

**Edit** to explain difference with "How do I import a local module?" This question is about differences between how IPython and Python handle local module imports, not how to import a local module.

I should also add that - while it is true that my example would work if I changed the import statement to `from a import foo` - I was (implicitly) trying to avoid doing this. I like the idea of importing everything relative to some top-level directory in order to make it easier if the structure of the files change. For example, if `b.py` was moved from `src` to some sub-directory `src/core` then you'd need to go through and rewrite all of the imports relative to the new location of `b.py`.

Comment: have you tried to put the entire path???

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: @Micolho, he is not just asking how to make it work, he is also asking why it works differently on **iPython**

Answer (score 0):

I cannot explain to you why that happens, but maybe it could work on **python** if you make the `b.py` file look like this:

> ```
> from a import foo
> foo()
> ```

For me, it doesn't make sense to use `src.a` because `src` is the (same) directory. But again, I do not know why one works and the other doesn't.
[Refer to the 3rd example on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749411/9686925)