# I am getting "module is not callable" error while trying to port Python 2.7 script to Python 3.6 (the queue module...)?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have in Python 2.7:

```
from Queue import Queue
self.queue = Queue()
```

What I'm trying so far to port to 3.6 looks like this:

```
import queue as queue
self.queue = queue()
```

But I'm getting "module is not callable"? I am bit of noob in Python :), it's likely a simple error, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python3 use

```
from queue import Queue
self.queue = Queue()
```

Comment: awsome that worked! will accept as answer in ~10 mins when it lets me ;)