# Im trying to import a module into my main.py python file both of which are in the same directory

Tags: python, function, import, module, call

```
def volumeofcube():
    a = int(input('Enter the length of the side:'))
    volume = a**3
    #Rounded to one decimal place
    volume = str(round(volume, 1))
    #The volume is added to its corresponding list
    volumeofcubelist.append(volume)
    print('The volume of the cube with the side', a,'is', volume)
    return volume
```

this is a funtion that i want to import into another file (main.py) to work like this:

```
elif shape == 'cube':
    volumeofcube()
```

however when I try to import:

```
import volumes
or
from volumes import volumeofcube()
```

none of these are able to find the volumes.py module and import it

Comment: `from volumes import volumeofcube` is the correct syntax for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: just `from volumes import volumeofcube` without `()` will do if your .py is named `volume`

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to import as

```
import volumes
```

the call for `volumeofcube` method should be

```
volumes.volumeofcube()
```

if you try to import as

```
from volumes import volumeofcube()
```

you need to take the parenthesis off, the right syntax is:

```
from volumes import volumeofcube
```

Comment: The correct syntax in the second case would be just `from volumes import volumeofcube` (i.e. with no parentheses at the end).