# In python what does the keyword "from" mean

Tags: python

```
  from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "your_auth_token"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

for sms in client.messages.list():
    print(sms.to)
```

here what is the meaning of keyword "from"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: Very simply, this is easy to  look up -- and we expect you to do so before posting here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Answer (score 1):

It allows you to import an element from a module without referencing the full module name to use it.

For example:

```
import time
time.sleep(10) # to sleep for 10 seconds
```

as opposed to

```
from time import sleep
sleep(10)
```

Comment: A *module*, not a class. It imports specific *names* from *modules*. `time` is a module, not a class.

Answer (score 0):

Allows you to import specific methods from a module without importing the entire library. If you want to import every method in that module, you can also use for example:

```
from pandas import *
```

Comment: This allows you to import specific *names*, not *methods*. While theoretically, a method could be bound to some module-level name, that is unlikely. You probably mean *function*