# python : various type of getting variables from other file

Tags: python, import, path, rules

can some give me right code to get variables from other file

getting variables or function from other python file

getting v in A.py to B.py
1. /var/www/Project/sub/A.py
   /var/www/Project/sub/B.py

```
B.y 

from A import v
```

2. /var/www/Project/sub/stuff/A.py
   /var/www/Project/sub/B.py

```
B.y

from stuff.A import v
```

3. /var/www/Project/sub/stuff/A.py
   /var/www/Project/sub/stuff/B.py

```
B.y

import os, sys

sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir)))

from stuff.B import v
```

4. /var/www/Project/sub/A.py
   /var/www/Project/sub/stuff/B.py

   B.y
   import os, sys

   sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(**file**), os.pardir)))

   from B import v

is this how system goes? is this code right?

Comment: If this question is about the problem from the previous question asked by you earlier today then the problem is circular import. Please learn about possible solutions from already answered questions - https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=python%20circular%20import.

Comment: @Poolka thanks for your solution(circular import), was just wondering about clean way to access other python file in several situation.  im aware of your answer about previous question i asked today:) thanks!

Comment: OK. Wish you luck with the research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Answer (score 0):

if you have two files at the same directory, you can simply import one file to the other:

test1.py:

```
a = 5
b = 10
```

test2.py:

```
import test1

print test1.a
print test1.b
```

or:

```
from test1 import a,b
print a
print b
```