# How to create a python script that import other imports

Tags: python

I would like to create a file that import other imports, e.g.

startup.py:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('qt5agg')
...
```

the just write

```
import startup
```

and have all of them.

is it possible?

Comment: you can do that in `__init__.py`

Comment: use : `from startup import *`

Answer (score 5):

It's not recommended for readability, but you could write:

```
from startup import *
```

in the file where you want to use `np` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files) older StackOverflow post which details many different ways to achieve what you want, and especially the excellent comment by 'Eric Leschinski'.

The simplest solution I'd check out first is to make a new directory and declare it as a package by creating an `__init__.py` file in there, which would contain the imports.

This dummy "package" of yours will be the input handler, and then from your main script you would `from root.parent.folder.file import class/variable/whatever`. The main drawback is that this disallows non-relative paths, but it's okay if all the project is self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you explicitly specify module that you wanted to be imported at the time of star import :)

Try the following example:

```
#example.py


import time
import random
import collections

__all__ = ['time', 'random']

$ python
>>> from example import *
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'random', 'time']
```

See how it didn't import `collections` module, because i didn't ask it to :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

startup.py

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

np = np

plt = plt
matplotlib = matplotlib
```

main.py

```
from startup import *

plt.show()
```

It's kinda ugly in my opinion, but works.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following:

Let file1 is **abc.py**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

Let file2 is **main.py**:

```
import abc

# Use pandas import as temp.pd
df = temp.pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2,3], 'B': [2,3,4]})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  B                                                                                                                                                               
0  1  2                                                                                                                                                               
1  2  3                                                                                                                                                               
2  3  4
```