# Importing modules from adjacent folders in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I wanted to ask if there is a way to import modules/functions from a folder in a project that is adjacent to another folder.

For example lets say I have two files:

```py
project/src/training.py
project/lib/functions.py
```

Now both these folders have the `__init__.py` file in them. If I wanted to import `functions.py` into `training.py`, it doesn't seem to detect. I'm trying to use `from lib.functions import *` .I know this works from the upper level of the folder structure, where I can call both files from a script, but is there a way to do it files in above/sideways folders?

Comment: This question is inconsistent. These are files, not folders. The init file is `__init__.py`, not `__init.py__`. You'd import one module from the other with `import functions`. Please create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: If the enclosing folder `project` has a `__init__.py` file in it, you can use relative imports: `from ..lib import functions`, or `from ..lib.functions import *` or something

Comment: Sorry, had some typos. Does this make more sense now?

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy doesn't seem to work

Comment: There's a wealth of questions about this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4383571/1394393, https://stackoverflow.com/q/16981921/1394393, https://stackoverflow.com/q/2349991/1394393, https://stackoverflow.com/q/279237/1394393, https://stackoverflow.com/q/72852/1394393 Admittedly, though, most of the top solutions are all very bad advice.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fundamentally, the best way of doing this depends on exactly how the two modules are related. There's two possibilities:

1. The modules are part of one cohesive unit that is intended to be used as a single whole, rather than as separate pieces. (This is the most common situation, and it should be your default if you're not sure.)
2. The `functions.py` module is a dependency for `training.py` but is intended to be used separately.

## Cohesive unit

If the modules are one cohesive unit, this is not the standard way of structuring a project in Python.

If you need multiple modules in the same project, the standard way of structuring the folders is to include all the modules in a single [package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages), like so:

```
project/
    trainingproject/
        __init__.py
        training.py
        functions.py
    other/
        ...
    project/
        ...
    folders/
        ...
```

The `__init__.py` file causes Python to recognize the `trainproject/` directory as a single unit called a package. Using a package enables to use of **relative imports**:

`training.py`

```
from . import functions

# The rest of training.py code
```

Assuming your current directory is `project`, you can then invoke `training.py` as a module:

```
python -m trainingproject.training
```

## Separate units

If your modules are actually separate packages, then the simplest idiomatic solutions *during development* is to modify the [`PYTHONPATH`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable:

sh-derviative syntax:

```
# All the extra PYTHONPATH references on the right are to append if it already has values
# Using $PWD ensures that the path in the environment variable is absolute.
PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH${PYTHONPATH:+:}$PWD/lib/
python ./src/training.py
```

PowerShell syntax:

```
$env:PYTHONPATH =  $(if($env:PYTHONPATH) {$env:PYTHONPATH + ';'}) + (Resolve-Path ./lib)
python ./src/training.py
```

(This is possible in Command Prompt, too, but I'm omitting that since PowerShell is preferred.)

In your module, you would just do a normal `import` statement:

`training.py`

```
import functions

# Rest of training.py code
```

Doing this will work when you *deploy* your code to production as well if you copy all the files over and set up the correct paths, but you might want to consider putting `functions.py` in a wheel and then installing it with pip. That will eliminate the need to set up `PYTHONPATH` by installing `functions.py` to site-packages, which will make the `import` statement just work out of the box. That will also make it easier to distribute `functions.py` for use with *other* scripts independent of `training.py`. I'm not going to cover how to create a wheel here since that is beyond the scope of this question, but here's [an introduction](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Comment: Thanks! this is what I was looking for, thanks for the comprehensive answer. I guess I do have to go the python path way since they are separate modules. I knew how to package the cohesive unit way, but this definitely covers all aspects of it

Comment: For the separate units creating a setup.py and running pip install -e has worked well.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it’s as simple as writing the entire path from the working directory:

```
from project.src.training import *
```

Or

```
from project.lib.functions import *
```

Comment: That's the issue, when I use this method, it tells me the top level folder is not a module, in this case 'project'

Comment: If you put a `__init__.py` inside the top-level folder, then it should work

Comment: Still says for me that `project` is not a package

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what polymath stated above. If you were also wondering how to run these specific scripts or functions once they are imported, use: your_function_name(parameters), and to run a script that you have imported from the same directory, etc, use: exec(‘script_name.py). I would recommend making functions instead of using the exec command however, because it can be a bit hard to use correctly.