# How do I import a function from a file located in a folder next to the parent folder

Tags: python, import, directory

Here's my project structure:

```
py_workshop/
├── app/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── script.py
│   └── time_module.py
└── tests/
    └── test_time_module.py
```

time_module.py's content:

```
import datetime


def current_time():
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

script.py's content:

```
from time_module import current_time

print(current_time())
```

test_time_module.py's content:

```
from app.time_module import current_time

print(current_time())
```

When I import current_time() from "app.time_module" into "test_time_module.py" I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "H:\dev\py-workshop\tests\test_time_module.py", line 1, in 
from ..app.time_module import *
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

I've googled for a possible solution and found out that I should add **init**.py to app/ and time_module/ to fix the error but it resulted in the same error.

I [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55484265/importing-modules-from-adjacent-folders-in-python) thread I found an answer that says I for a seperate unit as in my case I should change PYTHONPATH with `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH${PYTHONPATH:+:}$PWD/lib/` so I ran:
`PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH${PYTHONPATH:+:}$PWD/app/`

still no success!

I expect that when I run $ python tests/test_time_module.py I get the current time in this format: H:M:S

I'm very confused at this moment.

## Edit 1:

Current solution:

````
import sys

sys.path.append('../')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from app.time_module import *
    print(current_time())```
````

Comment: Add the parent folder to the system path using `import sys` and `sys.path.append('../')`

Comment: This would only work if I changed my test_time_module.py to:
import sys

sys.path.append('../')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from app.time_module import *
    print(current_time())

is this how am I supposed to write it typically or there are better alternatives?

Comment: You can add the absolute path to `py_workshop` instead of using a relative path.

Comment: You could install your project in [editable mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-e)

Answer (score 2):

The `PYTHONPATH` variable should contain the directory your `app` is located in, not the `app` directory itself.

So in your case it should be `H:\dev\py-workshop\`.

It looks like you're using Windows, so you should be able to set the `PYTHONPATH` using either Windows Command Prompt or PowerShell:

```
setx PYTHONPATH "%PYTHONPATH%;H:\dev\py-workshop\" /m
```

Then you can double-check that the `PYTHONPATH` is set correctly:

```
set PYTHONPATH
```