# How to simply import a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import

It seems a simple problem so I thought it would already be answered, but none of the explanations I found on the internet contained a solution that was valid for me.

So, I just want to be able to import functions from a file that is in the same folder as the file where I want to use them. It was written everywhere that I just had to write `import my_file`, but I just get a `ImportError: No module named my_file`

I tried to add an empty `__init__.py` file in the folder but it didn't work. I didn't try other too complicated solutions because there should be a simple one and I feel like I'm just missing something basic yet indispensable.

So, I made a test as simple as possible with just a folder `Folder` containing two files, `file1.py` and `file2.py`.
Here is the content of `file1.py`:

```
import file2
f()
```

And here is the content of `file2.py`:

```
def f():
    print "it works !"
```

When I execute `file1.py`, i get the following error at line 1:
`ImportError: No module named file2`

(I tried with all possible combinations presence and absence of quotes, parentheses and .py extension, with most of them I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`)

Comment: Is`Folder` in the python path ? can you execute the following before importing : `import sys; print sys.path`

Comment: Show exactly what you do to execute file1.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files   read this post please it will help u

Comment: Do you execute the script in the folder? Or in other path

Comment: This should "just work" (where the value of "work" is to produce the output `NameError: name 'f' is not defined`) if you execute `python file1.py`.

Comment: Adding `import sys; print sys.path` at the beginning prints this: `['', 'C:\\Windows\\system32\\python27.zip', 'c:\\python27\\DLLs', 'c:\\python27\\lib', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\plat-win', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\lib-tk', 'c:\\python27', 'c:\\python27\\lib\\site-packages']`. I use the Pyzo IDE, so I just open my file with it and run it inside the IDE

Comment: I also tried using the importlib module, but I think there's something I didn't get about the working directory

Comment: It's most likely a problem with your IDE, and you need to study its documentation.

Comment: I just tried adding the file to the system path (getting its path with `os.path.abspath(__file__)`) but I get `NameError: name '__file__' is not defined`

Comment: Try `from .file2 import f`

Comment: you should add `Folder` to your python path: `import sys; sys.path.append('<Path to Folder>')`

Answer (score 0):

you should write like below in file1.py:

```
from file2 import f
f()
```

Comment: I get the same error `ImportError: No module named file2`

Comment: Are you sure file1.py and file2.py in the same directory?

Comment: it does not make sense if the file1.py and file2.py in the same directory. I suggest  you Consider cleaning up the cache or reinstalling python

Comment: Yes they are in the same directory. I tried with another IDE and it worked, after asking where to execute the code from, so I guess it was a problem of working directory.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing in a wrong way Below is the code by which you will get your desired result:-

**file1**

```
import file2
file2.f()   # You have to use like this.
```

**file2**

```
def f():
    print "it works !"
```

I hope it may help you.

Comment: I still get the same error `ImportError: No module named file2`. file2 cannot be reached for import, so the way I call the function is not the problem

Comment: @Seldi it is working properly in my laptop. If you have used the code given above then it should work.

Comment: @Seldi Also make sure that both file1 and file2 are with `.py` extension

Comment: I did it, but it seems that the problem was coming from the IDE

Comment: @Seldi Make 2 files with these name with the help of notepad with `.py` extension like `file1.py` AND `file2.py`, AND then simplly run them into your powershell by `python file1.py` and if it is working then you will get your result. If it is working here then it can work in any IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Please use this, working fine for me.

## file1

```
from  file2 import f

#You will get object code. it means working fine.

print (f)
```

Comment: I still get the same error `ImportError: No module named file2`

Comment: Update your python, or reinstall your python version.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with another IDE (Spyder instead of Pyzo). It asked where to execute the code from, I clicked "from the file's location" and it worked.

I guess the problem was about where the code was executed from...