# Importing test libraries failed. No module named 'a'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, robotframework

I have a folder `/example` which contains `/Libs` which further contains different folders `/a`, `/b` each containing `python` libraries. I am trying to run a `robot` framework code from `/example`.

The error it shows :

> Importing test library 'a' failed: ImportError: No module named 'a'
>   File "/root/Libs/a/**init**.py", line 7, in 
>       from a import a_classname

How can I solve this?

Comment: I have provided a path to /Libs into PYTHONPATH.

Comment: Please share your code which you have tried till now.

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon As far, I know in python-2.7 we never write .py while import.

Comment: adding "--pythonpath /root/Libs/a " to my robot command helped me to import 'a'. But I have many libraries to import and can't afford to make robot command so lengthy. Is there any way to directly add these paths to PYTHONPATH?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Answer (score 1):

```
import os
import sys
filepath = "path/file/"
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(filepath))
from a import a_classname
```

Comment: Can I ask you, why append? why not insert?

Comment: I think you should use filepath = "path/to/"

Comment: @ComplicatedPhenomenon - Also can get problems if he executes the python script from other path, but thats not the main question, your question must solve his problem, cheers