# Get directory of imported file

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, python-os

I have a file in a package I am making that uses `os.getcwd()` to return the directory of the file.
For example:

```
# myfile1py

import os
def getfiledir():
    return os.getcwd()
```

The above code returns `C:\Users\Someone\Python36-32\Lib\site-packages\`, which is the correct directory of the file. When I import it, though, an issue occurs.

```
# myfile2.py

import myfile
print(myfile.getfiledir())
```

The above code is the code in `myfile2.py`. After importing `myfile1.py`, I ran the function `getfiledir()` and it returns the directory of `myfile2.py` (`C:\Users\Someone\Documents`) instead of the directory of the imported file (`myfile1.py`).

How do I get the code in `myfile2.py` return the directory of `myfile1.py`?

Keep in mind that I want the code that returns the directory to be in the imported file (`myfile1.py`), not the importer file.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this help?https://stackoverflow.com/q/57091689/7583919

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried it but it doesn't work because when the file with it is imported,  it adds the path of the importer file, not the imported file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the `os` module. It's on the standard library.

```
import os
os.path.dirname(myfile.__file__)
```

Further details: [How to retrieve a module's path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247770/how-to-retrieve-a-modules-path)

Comment: Thanks @11615853  I was using the wrong function. `os.path.dirname` worked.