# why python throws ModuleNotFoundError: No module named `blah`

Tags: python, import

I'm newbie on python so please understand me if this question is too easy.
I already searched out but I didn't understand accurately their answers.

---

## My question : What point I missed out for understanding python import system?

My project structure is like this (https://github.com/dingyo777/python_import_test):

```
-- python_import_test
    |-- deco
    |    |-- printer.py
    |    |-- decorator.py
    |
    |-- test.py
```

- printer.py imports decorater.py
- test.py imports printer.py

When I run `python test.py`, error is like this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    import deco.printer
  File "/Users/dingyo/Projects/my_repo/python_import_test/deco/printer.py", line 3, in <module>
    import decorator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'decorator'
```

---

Of course, it will be helpful if someone tell me how to resolve this error.
But more thing what I want to know is understanding how python import package or module accurately.

**Would you mind to explain what point I missed out?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: Also look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time) and generally search `python import` as there are a lot of really good questions/answers on the topic.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb Thank you for your advice :) 
Let me check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cd deco/
vim __init__.py
```

┓( ´-` )┏

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This answer has no explanation and as such is likely to attract down votes. Please don't include emoticon's in answers.

Comment: @JasonAller
Thank you for your response.
Please refer to https://github.com/dingyo777/python_import_test
It has `__init__.py` already.

┓( ´-` )┏

Comment: printer.py 
plan1. line3 `import decorator` changed to `import deco.decorator as decorator`
or
plan2. line3 `import decorator` changed to `import deco.decorator` and 
    line6 `print(decorator.decorate("test"))` changed to 
 `print(deco.decorator.decorate("test"))`

Comment: ```
import sys
print(sys.path)
from .decorator import decorate

def dec_print():
    print(decorate("test"))

dec_print()
```

Comment: You need to specify where the imported module or function comes from

Comment: @oaixnah Thank you for your advice :) It was really helpful for me.

Comment: @oaixnah May I ask one thing?
What is difference between `import deco.decorator` and `import decorator`? 
Why it works well when change to `import deco.decorator`?