# How to Import Python Code from Other Files

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, python-3.6

I have a simple situation on a linux system:

```
ls test_repo

example  __init__.py  text
```

In `text` directory, I just have 2 files:

```
__init__.py ex.py
```

In `example` directory, I have just 2 files again:

```
__init__.py test.py
```

In `ex.py` I have the code:

```
def test():
    print(10)
```

Now, in text directory I want to import it:

```
from text.ex import test

print(test())
```

But when I run the file in the example directory as well as out of it: `python test.py`

I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from text.ex import test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'text'
```

How can I import the function?

Should I put something in `__init__.py`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone having this import issue,let me explain how this work

first when you import certain module to a file,how does it know where to find the module?
when we import module,python check for that module in multiple locations.those locations are in `sys.path`.
If you print `sys.path` it will give a list of locations where python checks when we run an `import` statement.
in my machine output looks like this
[image]

so what are the values in this list

1. first value is just directory where my current script running
2. next values are directories listed in the python path environment variable
3. Standard library directories
4. site packages directory for third party packages

so python check all these location when you run an import.

when you run `python test.py` inside the example directory,this is what happens

1. Python add location where your current script running to the `sys.path` list (which is `test_repo/example`)
2. `test.py` file has import statement from `text.ex` module
3. Python search through all `sys.path` list to load `text.ex` module
4. since `ex.py` file  is inside the `test_repo/text` module and `sys.path` doesn't have the location for the `test_repo/text` it will gives the error No module named 'text'

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files), on StackOverflow. It has multiple examples for importing files, so just use the one that best fits in your situation.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you might add this into the very beginning line of your `test.py`

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "..")
```

Because your `test.py` is located inside `example` directory not the `root` directory.