# how do import a file given its string name?

Tags: python

alright, before marking as duplicate, listen out.
I have a file with some .py files. I want to import them, I would normaly do `import {the  name of the file I want}` but I want to chose the name of the file I want like so:

```py
file = input()
import file
```

what I have tried is:

```py
file = input()
exec('import',file)
```

which returns me an error,

```
file = input()
file = importlib.import_module(file)
```

also returns an error (no module found)
and:

```
file = input()
file = eval(f'import {file}')
```

which also gives me an error (invalid systax)

Comment: Also see this pip package: https://pypi.org/project/thesmuggler/

Answer (score 0):

[Duplicate of this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2349998/12240283)

`importlib` is recent addition in Python to programmatically import a module. It just a wrapper around `__import__` See https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#module-importlib

```py
import importlib
moduleName = input('Enter module name:')
importlib.import_module(moduleName)
```

If this does not work for you, look through linked thread at other options.