# pycharm does not impor the same location file

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm

let say I create the

```
model.py
utils.py
```

at the same folder 
but in utils.py

> from model import *
>   it does not recognize the model

is there something I have to set up?

Comment: I hope this helps you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files

Answer (score 0):

1. View => Tool Windows => Project (launch project sidepane)
2. Right click on folder containing the two scripts, Mark Directory as => Source Root