# Getting ImportError

Tags: python, module, importerror

I am learning intra package references. I have a main package `ecommerce`, in which there are two sub-packages, `shopping` and `customer`. In shopping I have `sales.py` file, and in `customer` I have `contact.py` file.

The `sales.py` has

```
from ecommerce.customer import contact
```

It gives the error `no module name ecommerce`. But there is an `app.py` file in the main folder, which is not part of shopping and customer sub packages, and in this file the above import works fine.

Comment: have u created __init__.py inside ecommerce package

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files

Comment: yes,i have created.it works fine in app.py,but it has problem in sales.py

Comment: @rajvi You mean `__init__.py`

Comment: yes that correct thanks @khelwood

Answer (score 1):

You're probably encountering this problem because of your **folder architecture**.

Let's say, as you state, that you run:

```
from ecommerce.customer import contact
```

What you actually tell Python here is to import `contact.py` (a Python file) from the subsubfolder `customer` located in the subfolder named `ecommerce`. If you **do not have** a subfolder named `ecommerce` in your working directory, then this **will not work**.

Now, you can note that it probably works in your main folder because (from what I'm guessing) this is where the subfolder named `ecommerce` is located.

---

If your file is located in another directory, what you can do is adding the path to your file to the Python path at runtime:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/ecommerce/shopping/customer')

# and then
import contact
```

Comment: ecommerce is the folder which contain shopping and customer subfolders

Comment: Ok! So then what is there in the `customer` subfolder? Is there a file named `contact.py`?

Comment: ,yes it contains contact.py

Comment: Ok! And now is the Python file that you are currently working on (the one where you get an error) located in the **same** directory as the `app.py` Python file?

Comment: No.it is shopping directory ,which is subdirectory under ecommerce directory,in shopping directory there is sales.py file there i am getting problem.

Comment: I've updated my answer: please tell me if this works!

Comment: Sir can you tell me why normal import did not work,i am doing mosh course,in that course he directly imported,didnt use sys module,can you explain me ,why i can not do for my solution..