# How do i import local variable to the another file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

from A.py to B.py file

**A.py file**

```
def ticket():
    .
    .
    .
    tickets = child + student + senior + adult
    total_price = child * Child_price + student * student_price + senior * senior_price + adult * adult_price
```

How can i import total_price from A.py file to B.py file

Comment: What does file ```B.py``` contains?

Comment: just want to print the output in B.py file

Comment: ```total_price``` is inside ```ticket``` function??

Comment: yeah it is inside ticket function

Comment: Does the below solution works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: This question is also not formatted well. Please format is well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the below solution:

You need to import file `A` in file `B` and return the value from file `B`

File A.py contains:

```
def ticket():
    .
    .
    .
    .
    tickets = child + student + senior + adult
    total_price = child * Child_price + student * student_price + senior * senior_price + adult * adult_price
    return(tickets,total_price)
```

Contents of file `B.py`:

```
from A import ticket
tickets,total_price= ticket()
print(tickets,total_price)
```

OR

```
import A
print(A.ticket())
```

OR

```
from A import ticket
print(ticket())
```

Comment: Does this solution works?

Comment: Obviously it will !

Comment: Still wanted to know whether is this what the user wants

Comment: i dn't want all function....i only want A.py total_price into B.py file.

Comment: i dn't want all function....i only want A.py total_price into B.py file.

Comment: That only I have done. I have only returned the value of ```total_price```

Comment: @sunilghimire check the updated solution. You can only import function ```ticket``` from ```A.py```

Comment: what if i want to import another variable like 
**tickets = child + student + senior + adult**
This tickets also is in ticket() function and wants that value in B.py file from A.py

Comment: You have to return the values from the function. Are you using classes?

Comment: A.py file contain 
def ticket():
.......
.......
       tickets = child + student + senior + adult
       total_price = child * Child_price + student * student_price + senior * senior_price + adult * adult_price


I want both the resultant value of A.py in B.py file

Comment: Return tickets too then

Comment: @sunilghimire Check the updated code