# "Import Error" : on importing admin files from one project folder to another under same directory in django

Tags: python, django

DIR path:
[Directory Tree.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u4QX.jpg)

***tests/admin.py:***

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from openwisp_utils.admin import AlwaysHasChangedMixin, ReadOnlyAdmin

from .models import Operator, Project, RadiusAccounting


@admin.register(Operator)
class OperatorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['first_name', 'last_name']


@admin.register(RadiusAccounting)
class RadiusAccountingAdmin(ReadOnlyAdmin):
    list_display = ['session_id', 'username']
    fields = ['session_id', 'username']


class OperatorForm(AlwaysHasChangedMixin, ModelForm):
    pass


class OperatorInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Operator
    form = OperatorForm
    extra = 0


@admin.register(Project)
class ProjectAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [OperatorInline]
    list_display = ['name']
```

**openwisp_utils/admin.py:**

```
from django.contrib.admin import ModelAdmin


class TimeReadonlyAdminMixin(object):
    """
    mixin that automatically flags
    `created` and `modified` as readonly
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.readonly_fields += ('created', 'modified',)
        super(TimeReadonlyAdminMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)


class ReadOnlyAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    """
    Disables all editing capabilities
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ReadOnlyAdmin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.readonly_fields = [f.name for f in self.model._meta.fields]

    def get_actions(self, request):
        actions = super(ReadOnlyAdmin, self).get_actions(request)
        if 'delete_selected' in actions:  # pragma: no cover
            del actions['delete_selected']
        return actions

    def has_add_permission(self, request):
        return False

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):  # pragma: nocover
        pass

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):  # pragma: nocover
        pass

    def save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change):  # pragma: nocover
        pass

    def change_view(self, request, object_id, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['show_save_and_continue'] = False
        extra_context['show_save'] = False
        return super(ReadOnlyAdmin, self).change_view(request,
                                                      object_id,
                                                      extra_context=extra_context)


class AlwaysHasChangedMixin(object):
    def has_changed(self):
        """
        This django-admin trick ensures the settings
        are saved even if default values are unchanged
        (without this trick new setting objects won't be
        created unless users change the default values)
        """
        if self.instance._state.adding:
            return True
        return super(AlwaysHasChangedMixin, self).has_changed()
```

**Error:**
[Error Snippet.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/af1ou.jpg)

**This import error is coming up upon migrating the above code....please help on how to fix this import error.**

Both **openwisp_utils** and **tests** files are under same parent folder.

Is there anything to change/add in the settings.py file of "tests" project before importing from "openwisp_utils"?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: My question is a bit different from that one.

Comment: Have you checked your python path? How are you running the code?

Comment: yes, I have checked my path and its in the correct directory inside django environment.