# Importing Inherited classes in Python

Tags: python, class, oop, import

when i was coding i used multiple python files that contains inherited classes, then when i wanted to import them to the main python file where we found the mother class it rises an Error:

lets say this is the architecture:

> .../myProject/main.py   **> The main python file "contains the parent Class "**
>
> .../myProject/child/... **> Where we found the other python files that contains inherited classes**

when i tried to import files from **.../myProject/child/...** to **main.py** it raises an Error:
`ImportError: No module named [Parent class]`

after some researches i found a method that solves the problem which is:
importing the **Parent class's file** to the **child file** but the problem here is that the child file is not in the same path.
is there any solutions to that.... or maybe **Another Method** please and thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: If you setup a regular import package for your project files, with `__init__.py` files in folders, you will be able to import from wherever you want inside your package.