# Hi I am gettin AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python

data = data.get('aggs')[0].get('subreddit')

df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(data)[0:10]

Comment: What data is stored in `data` ?

Comment: I got this code from this file https://pbpython.com/interactive-dashboards.html

Comment: data = get_pushshift_data(data_type="comment",
                          q="python",
                          after="48h",
                          size=1000,
                          aggs="subreddit")

Comment: Did you try "import requests" before the data.get line?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to import the packages (or modules) used in your code:

```
import requests
import pandas # this is missing from the article you referred to
```

Also, if you haven't installed Plotly, you'll want to do that with either
`pip install plotly` or `conda install plotly`.

There are several good articles about import and Python modules/packages, such as https://www.devdungeon.com/content/python-import-syspath-and-pythonpath-tutorial or [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)