# Functions in other files

Tags: python, function

How can I use functions that I have created before, in different python files and projects? for example functions that I have created in project A I want to use in project B.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: see this sample: https://repl.it/@willianvieira/BasicModuleImport

Answer (score 0):

A.py contains

```
def myFunction():
    print("Hello World")
```

you can call this function in your B.py 
by simply importing it

B.py contains

```
import A

A.myFunction()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import like any other library you import in your python file. For example if you have a python script A.py and you are writing another python script B.py and you want to use some methods of A then you just need to import like this:

```
from A import *
```

Will import all the methods of A.

you can import a specific method only like this:

`from A import method1`

Thanks hope it helps