# How to import self-made modules?

Tags: python, module, traceback

I created some simple modules for learning purposes containing simple classes and functions and tried to import it for the shell. Unfortunately TraceBack Error occurs.

I've checked `os.getcwd()` and I'm in the directory with all those modules. I also created modules with both pycharm and shell itself (`open("filename","w")` and stuff) and still python cannot find them.

Do you have any idea what's the reason of such matters?

```
import komendy
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/plugins/python-ce/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'komendy'
```

They are in same folder:

```
>>> os.listdir()
['komendy.py', 'zmienne.py', 'venv', 'mordeczko.txt', 'mordo', '.idea']
```

Ideas?

Comment: Can you check if your folder root project is in `python -m site sys.path`

Comment: ok appended sys.path and it works. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can import your library and its methods like this:

```
from komendy import *
```

Also check this:
[How to import other Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2349991/how-to-import-other-python-files)

Comment: doesn't work either, however sys.path.append trick did the work.